# How to update RecyclerView Adapter Data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to figure out what is the issue with updating `RecyclerView`'s Adapter.

After I get a new List of products, I tried to:

1. Update the `ArrayList` from the fragment where `recyclerView` is created, set new data to adapter, and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`; it did not work.
2. Create a new adapter, as others did, and it worked for them, but there wasn't any change for me: `recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(newArrayList))`
3. Create a method in `Adapter` which updates the data as follows:

   ```
    public void updateData(ArrayList<ViewModel> viewModels) {
       items.clear();
       items.addAll(viewModels);
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
   ```

   Then I call this method whenever I want to update the data list; it did not work.
4. To check if I can modify the recyclerView in any way, and I tried to remove at least an item:

   ```
     public void removeItem(int position) {
        items.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
   ```

Everything remained as it was.

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<ViewModel> items;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<ViewModel> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }


    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler, parent, false);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<ViewModel> viewModels) {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(viewModels);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void addItem(int position, ViewModel viewModel) {
        items.add(position, viewModel);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        items.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ViewModel item = items.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
        Picasso.with(holder.image.getContext()).load(item.getImage()).into(holder.image);
        holder.price.setText(item.getPrice());
        holder.credit.setText(item.getCredit());
        holder.description.setText(item.getDescription());

        holder.itemView.setTag(item);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        // Give some time to the ripple to finish the effect
        if (onItemClickListener != null) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    onItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, (ViewModel) v.getTag());
                }
            }, 0);
        }
    }

    protected static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView image;
        public TextView price, credit, title, description;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            credit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.credit);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClick(View view, ViewModel viewModel);

    }
}
```

And I initiate `RecyclerView` as follows:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 5));
adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(items);
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

So, how do I actually update adapter data in order to display newly received items?

---

The issue was that the layout where gridView was looked as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:tag="catalog_fragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            style="@style/FabStyle"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I just removed `LinearLayout` and made `FrameLayout` as the parent layout.

Comment: `items.clear(); items.addAll(newItems);` is an ugly pattern. If you really need defensive copying here, `items = new ArrayList(newItems);` would be less ugly.

Comment: @miha-x64 You're right - it would be less ugly. The problem is that this just don't work. The adapter gets no reference to the reference. It gets the reference itself. So if you build a new dataset it has a new reference while the adapter still only knows the old one.

Answer (score 398, accepted):

I'm working with RecyclerView and both the remove and the update work well.

1. ***Remove***:

   There are four steps to remove an item from a RecyclerView

   ```
    list.remove(position);
    recycler.removeViewAt(position);
    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());
   ```

   These lines of code work for me.
2. ***Update ALL the data***:

   The only things I had to do was:

   ```
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   ```

   > Which has no animation, because it affects all items.

You should do all of this where the "data" is managed, like Actvity/Fragment code, unless your RecyclerView's Adapter itself is the "data manager" (and has methods like "remove(int pos)" and "add(...)").

Comment: you only need these two lines: list.remove(position);
mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

Comment: I use list.remove(position), followed by notifyDataSetChanged and it seems to do the trick

Comment: I am using viewholder and when using viewholder for recycler view adapter, we can simply use `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside `onBindViewHolder()` after our events fire. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: An important consideration to avoid annoying glitch during the delete:
You don't need to call this line
recycler.removeViewAt(position);

Comment: NotifyDataSetChanged is overkill, specially if you are dealing with VERY long lists. Reload the whole thing for a few items? No, thanks. Also, recycler.removeViewAt(position)? Not needed. And don't need to call both "mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)" and "mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size())".
Remove some, or remove one. Notify ONCE. Call one of them.

Comment: please remove recycler.removeViewAt(position);

Comment: From the docs: "f you are writing an adapter it will always be more efficient to use the more specific change events if you can. Rely on notifyDataSetChanged() as a last resort." 

Source - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: This method of removing items by calling `removeViewAt` is **wrong** and **dangerous**.  It is completely unsupported, and it has only ever worked by coincidence.  In the absolute best case, it will **degrade performance** by **breaking the ability to recycle child views**.  If the child view contains a Compose view, it will **cause a memory leak**.  The [**correct answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48959184/208273) does not have these problems.

Answer (score 559):

This is a general answer. The various ways to update the adapter data are explained. The process includes two main steps every time:

1. Update the data set
2. Notify the adapter of the change

### Insert single item

Add "Pig" at index `2`.

[image: Insert single item]

```
String item = "Pig";
int insertIndex = 2;
data.add(insertIndex, item);
adapter.notifyItemInserted(insertIndex);
```

### Insert multiple items

Insert three more animals at index `2`.

[image: Insert multiple items]

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add("Pig");
items.add("Chicken");
items.add("Dog");
int insertIndex = 2;
data.addAll(insertIndex, items);
adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(insertIndex, items.size());
```

### Remove a single item

Remove "Pig" from the list.

[image: Remove single item]

```
int removeIndex = 2;
data.remove(removeIndex);
adapter.notifyItemRemoved(removeIndex);
```

### Remove multiple items

Remove "Camel" and "Sheep" from the list.

[image: Remove multiple items]

```
int startIndex = 2; // inclusive
int endIndex = 4;   // exclusive
int count = endIndex - startIndex; // 2 items will be removed
data.subList(startIndex, endIndex).clear();
adapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(startIndex, count);
```

### Remove all items

Clear the whole list.

[image: Remove all items]

```
data.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

### Replace old list with the new list

Clear the old list then add a new one.

[image: Replace old list with new list]

```
// clear old list
data.clear();

// add new list
ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
newList.add("Lion");
newList.add("Wolf");
newList.add("Bear");
data.addAll(newList);

// notify adapter
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The `adapter` has a reference to `data`, so it is important that I didn't set `data` to a new object. Instead, I cleared the old items from `data` and then added the new ones.

### Update single item

Change the "Sheep" item so that it says "I like sheep."

[image: Update single item]

```
String newValue = "I like sheep.";
int updateIndex = 3;
data.set(updateIndex, newValue);
adapter.notifyItemChanged(updateIndex);
```

### Move a single item

Move "Sheep" from position `3` to position `1`.

[image: Move single item]

```
int fromPosition = 3;
int toPosition = 1;

// update data array
String item = data.get(fromPosition);
data.remove(fromPosition);
data.add(toPosition, item);

// notify adapter
adapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
```

### Code

Here is the project code for your reference. The RecyclerView Adapter code can be found at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40584425/3681880).

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {

    List<String> data;
    MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // data to populate the RecyclerView with
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add("Horse");
        data.add("Cow");
        data.add("Camel");
        data.add("Sheep");
        data.add("Goat");

        // set up the RecyclerView
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvAnimals);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
                layoutManager.getOrientation());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, data);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View view) {
        insertSingleItem();
    }

    private void insertSingleItem() {
        String item = "Pig";
        int insertIndex = 2;
        data.add(insertIndex, item);
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(insertIndex);
    }

    private void insertMultipleItems() {
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("Pig");
        items.add("Chicken");
        items.add("Dog");
        int insertIndex = 2;
        data.addAll(insertIndex, items);
        adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(insertIndex, items.size());
    }

    private void removeSingleItem() {
        int removeIndex = 2;
        data.remove(removeIndex);
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(removeIndex);
    }

    private void removeMultipleItems() {
        int startIndex = 2; // inclusive
        int endIndex = 4;   // exclusive
        int count = endIndex - startIndex; // 2 items will be removed
        data.subList(startIndex, endIndex).clear();
        adapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(startIndex, count);
    }

    private void removeAllItems() {
        data.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void replaceOldListWithNewList() {
        // clear old list
        data.clear();

        // add new list
        ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        newList.add("Lion");
        newList.add("Wolf");
        newList.add("Bear");
        data.addAll(newList);

        // notify adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void updateSingleItem() {
        String newValue = "I like sheep.";
        int updateIndex = 3;
        data.set(updateIndex, newValue);
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(updateIndex);
    }

    private void moveSingleItem() {
        int fromPosition = 3;
        int toPosition = 1;

        // update data array
        String item = data.get(fromPosition);
        data.remove(fromPosition);
        data.add(toPosition, item);

        // notify adapter
        adapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }
}
```

### Notes

- If you use `notifyDataSetChanged()`, then no animation will be performed. This can also be an expensive operation, so it is not recommended to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` if you are only updating a single item or a range of items.
- Check out [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) if you are making large or complex changes to a list.

## Further study

- [CodePath: Using the RecyclerView](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview)
- [Smart way to update RecyclerView using DiffUtil](https://android.jlelse.eu/smart-way-to-update-recyclerview-using-diffutil-345941a160e0)

Comment: Awesome answer! What would be the steps when replacing a in item, which would result in a different view type? Is it just notifyItemChanged or a combined remove followed by an insert?

Comment: With your minimal example, it looks like notifyItemChanged is sufficient. It will call onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder for the changed item and the different view is shown. I had a problem in an application updating an item which would result in a different view, but there seems to be another problem.

Comment: @Suragch any idea about my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332222/how-do-i-update-my-recycleview-button-state-on-click-after-alertdialog-confirmat/57333319?noredirect=1#comment101161176_57333319 I tried everything listed in this thread but to no avail :(

Comment: How about when we use DiffUtils to make changes? They are not so fluid like calling manually .notify<Action>().

Comment: Really dropped the ball under `Update single item`, should have been **I like turtles**

Comment: Have you or has someone updated this answer for Kotlin?

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva, I haven't but I would welcome someone to add a Kotlin version.

Comment: Why replacing old list with new list for completely dataset updating? Isn't it a performance issue?

Comment: @ATES, I never noticed a performance issue, but I probably never had a list longer than 100 items, either.

Comment: Hi, I'm still a newbie. Is there a way to update the index that's displayed on the View? My problem is that I have to display the index of each item in the RecyclerView. So, when I do a remove or insert, the indices aren't updating, e.g. I have a list of `{"one", "two", "three", "four"}` and I do a remove at index `1` (contains element `two`), what I want is RecyclerView to update the View that's displaying the index of element `three`, `four`, ..., accordingly. Here's what I don't want to happen: https://i.imgur.com/rLjyp1W.png

Comment: cont. I can achieve it by using the `notifyDataSetChanged` method, but it removes the animation, and I want to keep the animation.

Comment: @LuckMan, I'd recommend asking this as a new question. I'm mostly working with Flutter now so I've kind of forgotten about the details of how to do Android development.

Comment: Never mind. I managed to do it using `notifyItemRangeChanged`.

Comment: Came across with your answer and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 50):

This is what worked for me:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(newList));
recyclerView.invalidate();
```

After creating a new adapter that contains the updated list (in my case it was a database converted into an ArrayList) and setting that as adapter, I tried `recyclerView.invalidate()` and it worked.

Comment: wouldn't this refresh the entire view instead of just updating the items that have changed?

Comment: Instead of making a new adapter each time, what I did was to create a setter method in my custom adapter class to set the new list.

After that, just call `YourAdapter adapter = (YourAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter(); adapter.yourSetterMethod(newList); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` That being said, it sounds like what the OP tried first (just adding this on as a comment so that it may help someone else, as that worked in my case).

Comment: Reader, don't settle for this. This answer works, but there's a more efficient way. Instead of reloading *all data again*, the most efficient way is just add the new data to the adapter.

Comment: Yes I agree with @TWilly it will redraw complete View on UI.

Comment: If this is the only solution that works for you, **you have a serious bug in your code**.  Even if you don't have any idea what changed, `notifyDataSetChanged()` should be sufficient.  If that doesn't work, something about your adapter is seriously broken (quite possibly it is not resetting views properly).  Also, the `invalidate()` is pointless; that should happen anyway after `setAdapter`.

Answer (score 22):

You have two options to do this:

Refresh the UI from the adapter:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Or refresh it from the recyclerView itself:

```
recyclerView.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 16):

Another option is to use [diffutil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html). It will compare the original list against the new list and use the new list as the update if there is a change.

Basically, we can use DiffUtil to compare the old data vs. new data and let it call notifyItemRangeRemoved, and notifyItemRangeChanged and notifyItemRangeInserted on your behalf.

A quick example of using diffUtil instead of notifyDataSetChanged:

```
DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil
                .calculateDiff(new MyDiffUtilCB(getItems(), items));

//any clear up on memory here and then
diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);

//and then, if necessary
items.clear()
items.addAll(newItems)
```

I do the calculateDiff work off the main thread in case it's a big list using [AsyncListDiffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/AsyncListDiffer)

Comment: although this is correct, how do update the data inside your adapter? Let's say I am displaying List<Object> in the adapter and I get a new update with List<Object>. DiffUtil will calculate a difference and dispatches it in the adapter, but it is doing nothing with the original or new list (in your case `getItems()`. How do you know which data from original list need to be removed/added/updated?

Comment: Maybe this article can help. ..  https://medium.com/@nullthemall/diffutil-is-a-must-797502bc1149#.9e7v4tsv8

Comment: @vanomart you only have to directly replace your local list field with the new list value as you would normally do, the only difference in this approach is that instead of notifyDataSetChanged() you use DiffUtil to update the view.

Comment: any idea about mine ? i tried everything listed here but no luck : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332222/how-do-i-update-my-recycleview-button-state-on-click-after-alertdialog-confirmat/57333319?noredirect=1#comment101161176_57333319

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you please explain why I should put the "clear" & "addAll" after the dispatchUpdatesTo?? Tnx!

Comment: it was just an example, you can ignore it or search the web how to use it. i was just making a quick example

Comment: @j2emanue You mention to do the calculateDiff work of the main thread in case it's a big list.  Can that be done in the adapter and then still update the UI correctly?  Do you have any examples to show how to do off the main thread?

Comment: @AJW just use this for async work or design your own:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/AsyncListDiffer

Comment: @j2emanue Thanks, I was able to set up an adapter with AsyncListDiffer but cannot get sorting to work on the RecyclerView list:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70318907/android-how-to-sort-recyclerview-list-when-using-asynclistdiffer/70474452?noredirect=1#comment124701152_70474452.  Any ideas on how to sort a list when the Adapter uses AsyncListDiffer?

Comment: If your list isn't big I wouldn't even bother doing it on a child thread. This sounds like a difficult thing that you want to do because you're changing the list when you sort it.  I would just stick with filterable which does the filtering on a child thread. Because you'd want to sort on a child thread if it's a big list.... https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable?hl=id

Answer (score 10):

Update the data of listview, gridview and recyclerview:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Or:

```
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, itemList.size());
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to update my data until the user starts scrolling. I've looked all over the place and can't figure why..

Comment: @SudoPlz you can use custom scroll listener for detect scroll and perform your notify operation like https://stackoverflow.com/a/31174967/4401692

Comment: Thanks Pankaj but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.
I want to update everything WITHOUT having the user touch the screen.

Answer (score 7):

I've solved the same problem in a different way.
I don't have data. I am waiting for it from the background thread, so start with an empty list.

```
mAdapter = new ModelAdapter(getContext(), new ArrayList<Model>());
// Then when I get data

mAdapter.update(response.getModelList());
// And update it in my adapter

public void update(ArrayList<Model> modelList){
    adapterModelList.clear();
    for (Product model: modelList) {
        adapterModelList.add(model);
    }
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

That's it.

Comment: I don't get ist. Your code doesn't make any sense to me. Why should you loop over a list to add it's items to another list? And why ist the class "Product" compatible to "Model". Why not just call "mAdapter = new ModelAdapter(getContext(),response.getModelList());" or copy the list from response at once?

Comment: dies in `addAll`

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest you to explore [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil). It also improves RecyclerView's performance while handling list updates.

1. Define a variable inside your Adapter:

   ```kotlin
    differList = AsyncListDiffer(this, this.callback);     
    differList.submitList(list)
   ```

Here, the list can be your initial raw list, or simply an empty list provided that you will be updating it later on.

2. Implementing callback:

   ```
   private val callback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item> = object: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item>() {

      override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item) =
        oldItem.id == newItem.id

      override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item) =
        oldItem == newItem
    }
   ```
3. Also, in the same adapter you will have some public function to set the list.

   ```kotlin
    fun setData(list: List<Item>) {
           differList.submitList(list)
           //yeah, that's it!
    }
   ```

4. Now, after you made any changes to your list(insert/update/delete), just invoke this **setData(list)** from your fragment/activity.

   `mAdapter.setData(list)`

Easy, right?

Answer (score 6):

The best and the coolest way to add new data to the present data is

```
 ArrayList<String> newItems = new ArrayList<String>();
 newItems = getList();
 int oldListItemscount = alcontainerDetails.size();
 alcontainerDetails.addAll(newItems);           
 recyclerview.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(oldListItemscount+1, al_containerDetails);
```

Comment: I see people using the "notifyDataSetChanged" for EVERYthing, isn't that overkill? I mean, reload the whole list because a few changed or were added... I like this approach, was implementing right now, with the "notifyItemRangeInserted" method.

Answer (score 3):

These methods are efficient and good to start using a basic `RecyclerView`.

```
private List<YourItem> items;

public void setItems(List<YourItem> newItems)
{
    clearItems();
    addItems(newItems);
}

public void addItem(YourItem item, int position)
{
    if (position > items.size()) return;

    items.add(item);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void addMoreItems(List<YourItem> newItems)
{
    int position = items.size() + 1;
    newItems.addAll(newItems);
    notifyItemChanged(position, newItems);
}

public void addItems(List<YourItem> newItems)
{
    items.addAll(newItems);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clearItems()
{
    items.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addLoader()
{
    items.add(null);
    notifyItemInserted(items.size() - 1);
}

public void removeLoader()
{
    items.remove(items.size() - 1);
    notifyItemRemoved(items.size());
}

public void removeItem(int position)
{
    if (position >= items.size()) return;

    items.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public void swapItems(int positionA, int positionB)
{
    if (positionA > items.size()) return;
    if (positionB > items.size()) return;

    YourItem firstItem = items.get(positionA);

    videoList.set(positionA, items.get(positionB));
    videoList.set(positionB, firstItem);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You can implement them inside of an Adapter Class or in your Fragment or Activity but in that case you have to instantiate the Adapter to call the notification methods. In my case I usually implement it in the Adapter.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that a really simple way to reload the RecyclerView is to just call

```
recyclerView.removeAllViews();
```

This will first remove all content of the RecyclerView and then add it again with the updated values.

Comment: Please do not use this. You'll be asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you to use `[DiffUtil.ItemCallback][1]` to handle the change in `RecyclerView.Adapter`:

```kotlin
fun setData(data: List<T>) {
    val calculateDiff = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(DiffUtilCallback(items, data))
    items.clear()
    items += data
    calculateDiff.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
}
```

Under the hood it handles most of the things with `AdapterListUpdateCallback`:

```java
/**
 * ListUpdateCallback that dispatches update events to the given adapter.
 *
 * @see DiffUtil.DiffResult#dispatchUpdatesTo(RecyclerView.Adapter)
 */
public final class AdapterListUpdateCallback implements ListUpdateCallback {
    @NonNull
    private final RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    /**
     * Creates an AdapterListUpdateCallback that will dispatch update events to the given adapter.
     *
     * @param adapter The Adapter to send updates to.
     */
    public AdapterListUpdateCallback(@NonNull RecyclerView.Adapter adapter) {
        mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void onInserted(int position, int count) {
        mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(position, count);
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void onRemoved(int position, int count) {
        mAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, count);
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void onMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void onChanged(int position, int count, Object payload) {
        mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, count, payload);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With Kotlin I would use, The Adapter.,

```
class ProductAdapter(var apples: List<Apples>?= null) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder {...}

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {...}

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {...}

    fun setData(newApples: List<Apples>) {
        apples = newApples
    }
}
```

In Fragment/Activity

```
val appleAdapter = ProductAdapter()

val recyclerView = binding.appleRecycler // or findViewById or synthetics or whatever. 
recyclerView.adapter = appleAdapter
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
```

Now handling the data changes in fragment

```
fun updateRecyclerData(apples: List<Apples>){
    adapter.setData(apples)
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

updateRecyclerData(applesList)
```

Comment: this one best so far

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer after a long time:

```
SELECTEDROW.add(dt);
notifyItemInserted(position);
SELECTEDROW.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine Try it.

```
  ArrayList.remove(position);
  notifyItemRemoved(position);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If nothing mentioned in the above comments is working for you, it might mean the problem lies somewhere else.

One place I found the solution was in the way I was setting the list to the adapter. In my activity the list was a instance variable and I was changing it directly when any data changed. Due to it being a reference variable there was something weird going on.

So I changed the reference variable to a local one and used another variable to update data and then pass to `addAll()` function mentioned in the previous answers.