# Update recyclerView Adapter without scrolling to top

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

am trying to update my adapter after adding some data in it but its not updating , when i switch through other activities and come back the adapter got updated this time my code :

```
    void updateAdapter(){
    adapter.setData(getData());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d("TAG"," DATA SIZE AFTER UPDATE : "+getData().size() +" items : "+adapter.getItemCount());

}
```

my adapter :

```
    private void createAdapter(final RecyclerView recyclerView , final List<Information> data) {
    List<Information> content = new ArrayList<>();

    Log.d("TAG","createAdapter Called");

    final int[] currentRowPosition = {0};
    content = data;
    final List<Information> finalContent = content;
     adapter = new ParallaxRecyclerAdapter<Information>(finalContent) {

/// my onBindViewHolder
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolderImpl(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final ParallaxRecyclerAdapter<Information> adapter, final int i) {


            currentRowPosition[0] = i;

            if ( i <= finalContent.size() -1 ){

                ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            final Information current = finalContent.get(i);

            ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).DESCRIPTION.setText(current.description);

        }else {

                 // this is my loadMore button which stays at the last row of recyclerView 
                ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).setIsRecyclable(false);
                ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).itemView.getLayoutParams().height = 100;


                ((ViewHolder) viewHolder).LOADMORE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        fetchNext();
                    }
                });

            }

        }
//my on create View Holder
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolderImpl(ViewGroup viewGroup, final ParallaxRecyclerAdapter<Information> adapter, int i) {

            return  new ViewHolder(getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_row, viewGroup, false));

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCountImpl(ParallaxRecyclerAdapter<Information> adapter) {
            return finalContent.size()+1;
        }
    });
// adding header to recyclerView  
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    View header = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, recyclerView, false);

    headerImageView =  (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.headerImageView);
    //setting CoverImage

    adapter.setParallaxHeader(header, recyclerView);

    adapter.setData(content);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

any idea how can i add new items with realtime updation on my RecyclerView ?? any guidance will be so helpful for me

Comment: How are you adding new data? in separate activity? Could you also add your code for activity that hosts recyclerView

Comment: yes in  same activity  , `updateAdapter` is where am adding new data @Marat

Comment: Instead of refreshing whole recylceView you can simply refresh a single item see this [How to update/refresh specific item in RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457406/how-to-update-refresh-specific-item-in-recyclerview).

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that when you run the `Activity` (which has `RecyclerView`) for the first time it loads everything from the `adapter` properly.

But when you change to other `activities` which would change items to your `adapter` and come back to your `Activity` which has `RecyclerView` in it can't get the proper updated information as `adapter` is not updated.

This may be because you are not refreshing your adapter when your activity resumes in [onResume()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()), something like this. you may have to make other changes to your onResume method as required,

```
onResume(){
  if(adapter != null){
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

Kindly check the lifecycle of an `Activity`

[image]

Example:
This does not directly addresses your issue but help you understand as you come back to `activity` you should refresh the `adapter`.

There is a [NoteListActivity](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/activities/list/first/NoteListActivity.java), with ListView in it, you may Add or edit items to the Adapter in it in [NoteEditActivity](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/activities/list/first/NoteEditActivity.java) and as soon as you come back you have to refresh the `adapter` in the `activity` where you have your `listview`

Answer (score 1):

> Adapter.class

```
public void add(List<Information> informations){
try{
finalContent.addAll(informations);
}catch(Exception e){
e.printstacktrace();
}
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: what is content here ? @narendra ?? and how about using `adapter.addItem(item , position )` ?

Comment: call this function from Activity to add list of info in listview.

Comment: this function will add data at last of your list

Comment: alright thats what exactly i want , to add item at last and i tired your code but whats content here ???

Comment: you set listData as finalContent in your adapter. I just used that finalContents... see my edited answer...

Comment: got it or still not ?

Comment: well i got it working , thanks a lot for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

well i ended up with this :

```
   int offset =   adapter.getItemCount();
    for(int l=0; l<= 4 ; l++){ 

        Log.d("TAG","getData : "+getData().size());
        if ((offset - 2) + l < getData().size()){

            adapter.addItem(getData().get((offset - 2 ) + l) , adapter.getItemCount() - 2);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
```

what i needed was `adapter.addItem(item , position)` and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` the above example is loading 5 images at a time