# How to save or change each row state on recyclerview item clicked?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have created a horizontal recyclerview list. below is the image I have attached.
problem is that I have to change bulb state when everytime user clicked that row from off state to on state and on state to off state.
How do I implement this logic? please help me to find out the solution.
**i want to change light color according to user clicks, if he clicks on then it should change its color for that row and vise versa**

[image: horizontal recyclerview]

```
public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            //toast("clicked" + position );
            if (!lightClicked){
                ImageView lightPopUp = view.findViewById(R.id.row_light_thumbnail);
                DrawableCompat.setTint(lightPopUp.getDrawable().mutate(), ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.white));
                //toast("light on");
                lightClicked = true;
            }else {
                ImageView lightPopUp = view.findViewById(R.id.row_light_thumbnail);
                //toast("light off");
                DrawableCompat.setTint(lightPopUp.getDrawable().mutate(), ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorAccent));
                lightClicked = false;
            }
            //View view1 = mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(position);


        }
```

Comment: you can create a listener(onclick) and change the image according to the state

Comment: if all elements are in off state, if clicks other elements it goes to on state and vice versa i.e, again user clicks that elements it comes back to the original state or off state.

Comment: what simple logic?

Comment: Just check the states in if condition if on then on_image and if off then off_image in recyclerview adapter onbind method

Comment: I added logic which I am using please check and help me

Comment: use             notifyDataSetChanged(); method inside onclick.

Comment: post your adapter class and activity/fragment class as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update/refresh specific item in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457406/how-to-update-refresh-specific-item-in-recyclerview)

Comment: @BhanuPro: have you resolved this issue...?
plz check my solution below

Comment: @PragyaMendiratta still not solved bro. can explain how your code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont directly do this change as the recycler view's cells are reused and it wont work as expected, so instead apply the change in the list you are using. You can add a boolean variable in the model class of the list you use to populate the recycler view, and than on its click you can change the boolean's value and call notifydatasetchange on the adapter, and in bind view you should keep an If else condition based on that boolean for the Bulb's image
ie. if true set one image if false set another

Comment: Actually, I am not using model class. i am using ArrayList

Comment: then you can create a model class with one string and boolean, and use that as an object in arraylist

Comment: sure I will do.

Answer (score 0):

declare this :

```
int selectedPosition=-1;
```

inside onBindViewHolder:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(FiltersAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
if(selectedPosition==position)
  holder.itemView.setImageResource(R.drawable.higlihgt_image);
else
   holder.itemView.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal_image);

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedPosition=position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: so this works for all the rows clicks or I need to declare each item positions?

Comment: globaly define this int .... and replace your according to my solution...It will definitely work

Comment: above answer solved my problem. and thanks for your answer