# How to check if new added item exist in recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually i'm developing an inventory app where i scan some EAN codes then i insert the quantity of an item and then i add it to an ArrayList in recyclerView.

For now i had no problem as i've made the inventory part where the items had to have different lines for each in recyclerView but now i have to make the order part and here if an item exist yet in ArrayList i have to sum it's quantity and put it to top of recyclerView.

I was trying to make something like a for loop when i'm going to add a new item and check if it's exist in ArrayList, if it's exist i was going to sum that item quantity with old one but the problem was that sometimes the app was going to crash and that the item wasn't going on top of recyclerView.

Do you have any suggestion on how can i do it?

```
for (ItemModel item : itemModel) {
    if (item.getCodiceArticolo()
            .equals(code.getText()
                        .toString())) {
        item.setQta(String.valueOf(
                Integer.parseInt(item.getQta()) + 1));
    }
}
```

I was trying to make something like that.

Comment: add your error log.

Comment: @AndroidTeam actually i was getting "ConcurrentModificationException" but now i'm trying another approach and it's not crashing anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three days a go i was getting the "ConcurrentModificationException" but now i'm trying another approach inspired by other answers or better the following one:

```
boolean nuovo = true;
for (ItemModel itemModels : itemModel) {
    if (itemModels.getCodiceArticolo()
                  .equals(code.getText()
                              .toString())) {
        itemModels.setQta(String.valueOf(
                Integer.parseInt(itemModels.getQta()) + 1));
        nuovo = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (nuovo) {
    itemModel.add(new ItemModel(
            code.getText()
                .toString(),
            "1"));
}
```

And is not crashing anymore and seems to work fine.

Thank's all for suggestions.

**UPDATE**

THANKS TO kartik malik ANSWER i was able to even "update" my items by adding the last one added on top, as i'm using reverse recyclerView i've done it by this wasy instead of putting the item to position 0

```
ItemModel matchedItem = null;
int matchedItemIndex = -1;
boolean nuovo = true;
for (ItemModel itemModels : itemModel) {
    if (itemModels.getCodiceArticolo()
                  .equals(code.getText()
                              .toString())) {
        itemModels.setQta(String.valueOf(
                Integer.parseInt(itemModels.getQta()) +
                Integer.parseInt(qta.getText()
                                    .toString())));
        MediaPlayer mpFound = MediaPlayer.create(
                OrdiniActivity.this,
                R.raw.errorsound);
        mpFound.start();
        matchedItem = itemModels;
        matchedItemIndex = itemModel.indexOf(itemModels);
        nuovo = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (matchedItemIndex > -1) {
    itemModel.remove(matchedItem);
    itemModel.add(matchedItem);
}

if (nuovo) {
    itemModel.add(new ItemModel(
            code.getText()
                .toString(),
            qta.getText()
               .toString()));
}
```

With the boolean i'm checking if the item exist or not and if it doesn't exist i add the item as a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
ItemModel matchedItem = null;
int matchedItemIndex = -1;
for (ItemModel item : itemModel) {
    if (item.getCodiceArticolo()
            .equals(code.getText()
                        .toString())) {
        item.setQta(String.valueOf(
                Integer.parseInt(item.getQta()) + 1));
        matchedItem = item;
        matchedItemIndex = itemModel.indexOf(item);
        break;
    }
}

if (matchedItemIndex > -1) {
    itemModel.remove(matchedItem);
    itemModel.add(
            0,
            matchedItem);
    notifyItemMoved(index,
                    0);
}
```

Comment: if you are using reverse recycler view then you should add matched item at top of array list, so just use `itemModel.add(matchedItem)`. it will add it at top for you. and change this also `notifyitemMoved(index,data.size());`

Comment: thank you, that's what i've tryed :) but i actually no need the notifyitemMoved as the recyclerView is going to be open in an alertDialog so the item are moved on create of it, your answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You do not adderror log to your list, so I guess your program crashes because sometimes there is a value that has no quantity (there is no valid number) and therefore can not parse the number, so in this case you just write that there is one item in list that has not been there yet.

```
for (ItemModel item : itemModel) {
    if (item.getCodiceArticolo()
            .equals(code.getText()
                        .toString())) {
        try {
            item.setQta(String.valueOf(
                    Integer.parseInt(item.getQta()) + 1));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            item.setQta(String.valueOf(1));
        }
    }
}
```

If this does not help, please attach error log.

Comment: I was getting the "ConcurrentModificationException" but by trying something similar to your method ( i've posted in an answer what i'm using now ) it's not crashing anymore and seems to work.

Comment: Now the one issue i have is that the updated item doesn't go on top of recyclerView

Comment: move it to first position in your adapter's list. donwt forget to call invalidate.

Answer (score 1):

Since the app is crashing, your ArrayList might not have been initialized as suggested in the comments.

For checking if the item exists you can use

```
if (arraylist_of_items != null && arraylist_of_items.contains(item)) {
  // do your stuff here
}
```