# How to sum checked items data values in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My problem is how to sum all checked items values, and how to manage their changed at check/uncheck events?
This is my method for check box toggle (check/uncheck) event.

```java
holder.itemCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) 
    {
      double price = Double.parseDouble(catalogDatabases.get(position).getPriceItem());
      holder.totalPrice = holder.totalPrice + price;
      holder.listener.respond(holder.totalPrice);
    } 
    else {
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you talking about a List adapter ? Your purpose is to save the sum of all checked items ?

Comment: @RamiLoiferman yes

Comment: What's the type of `holder.totalPrice`?

Comment: @RamiLoiferman 'double totalPrice = 0;'

Comment: @afiq, Can you clear what is the problem you faced to do so?

Comment: @RamiLoiferman i'm doing to sum all data when checked the box in my recyclerview. So how to sum all value is checked. that value take from position is selected and pass value to interface.

Comment: Instead of holder put the `totalPrice` in your adapter

Comment: Can you add here your onBingViewOlder method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all don't rely on the view as data.
I'll explain in your code

> if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())

You relying on view's isChecked method.
This may cause a bug because of android list recycling mechanism.

You can read about it in the link below
[How ListView's recycling mechanism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

TL;DR views are being recycled so when you scroll your list.
So for example the user checked item number 3 and then scrolled the list down item number 13 for example may also be shown as checked even tho it isn't .

So when onClick triggers we need to save the checked state in some list

After the theoretical intro i'll show it in code.

```
//Here you'll need to create some boolean array or list to store
//checked not checked positions lets call it checked
boolean[] checkedArr = new boolean[catalogDatabases.size()];
// catalogDatabases.size represents your data set size
// note that all items will be false initially

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        /**
         * Other views binding.......
         */
        holder.itemCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                checkedArr[position] = isChecked;
                sumAllCheckedAndNotify();
            }
        }
        );
    }
```

(I decided to do the calculation on every check it more straight forward from making an update on the event)

```
    private void sumAllCheckedAndNotify() {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < checkedArr.length; i++) {
            if(checkedArr[i]) {
                sum += Double.parseDouble(catalogDatabases.get(i).getPriceItem());
            }
        }
        // pudate the listener
        listener.respond(sum, selectedCount);
    }
```

Comment: mean size is catalogDatabases.size()?

Comment: notifyItemChanged is a build in method of list adapter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457406/how-to-update-refresh-specific-item-in-recyclerview

Comment: Are you using recyclerview adapter ?

Comment: yes and boolean isChecked at second will error it because same at first name boolean so when i cange it will not use the second one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204961/discussion-between-rami-loiferman-and-afiq).

Answer (score 0):

Store `totalPrice` inside adapter and add/subtract value based on `CheckBox` state like below:

```
class YourAdapter extends ... {

    double totalPrice = 0;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerHolder holder, int position) {

       holder.itemCheckBox.setChecked(catalogDatabases.get(position).isSelected());

       holder.itemCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                double price = Double.parseDouble(catalogDatabases.get(position).getPriceItem());

                boolean isSelected = !catalogDatabases.get(position).isSelected();
                catalogDatabases.get(position).setSelected(isSelected);

                if (isSelected) {
                    totalPrice += price;
                } else {
                    totalPrice -= price;
                }

                holder.listener.respond(totalPrice);

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Update your *Model* to hold checked/ unchecked state to persist data

```
class CatalogDatabase { //Assume this is your model class

    private boolean isSelected

    ....

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: ((CheckBox) v).isChecked() can be incorrect because the list view recycling mechanism