# How to update/refresh data of selected item from RecyclerView

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, android-viewmodel, selecteditem

I have a recyclerview that its data come from viewModel and database using retrofit. I know how to update all data of recyclerview every time that I want. but when I go to the selected item page using navigation component with selected item data as its argument, I don't know how to update data of this page (using e.g. swiperefresh).

I can update all data, that its output is a `List`, but I don't know how to find the selected item among the list. It is easy in `Array` case using `index` but here it is a List. Any simple solution?

here are some related posts but I couldn't use them:

[Convert list to array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9572795/21193451)

[Converting 'ArrayList<String> to 'String[]' in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4042434/21193451)

[How to update/refresh specific item in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32457406/21193451)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- For loop

  ```
  for(MyClass item: currentList){
    if(item.getId() == yourItem.getId(){
      return item;
    } 
    return null; //Item Not found.
  }
  ```
- Or if you have the item position in the recyclerview you can use : `currentList.get(position)`

Comment: recyclerview items and consequently their positions may change each time since some new items. So I think I cannot use 'currentList'!