# RecyclerView Changing Values on Scrolling

Tags: android

I have recyclerview listing which have two buttons. Add to Cart or Go To Cart. One of them Visibility is gone.
When i click on add to cart button. It will hiding the add to cart button and show the go to cart button.its working fine.
But when i scroll the recyclerview list then it automatically change the button to Add to cart.
Please help me to sort out this problem
Thanks

Comment: While asking questions on StackOverflow it's a good practice to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should manage one boolean variable in Model class. Because your list is updated, but you recycleview is not notified so that you have to update the list and the notify adapter.

Comment: Can you please show me some example...?

Comment: go through below link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data