# Edit item is not store into correct position in recyclerview using Realm Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to create a task application, where I am using Realm as a local database. I am showing this Task in recyclerview. At this moment I can add a new task with title, date and time. But When I try to edit an item the recyclerview is not updated. Also after deleting one item, the list is showing wrong. for example, if I click task 1, it shows task 2 inside it and when to click task 2 it shows task 1 inside it. My AddTaskActivity Class is,

**Edited Add Task Activity**

```
public class TodoAddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Variables
private Context mContext;

private Realm realm;
private TodoModel task;
private Button button;
private EditText mTaskNameEditText;
private EditText mTaskDateEditText;
private EditText mTaskTimeEditText;
String time;

private RealmResults<TodoModel> results;

public final static String INTENT_KEY_ID = "taskId";
public final static String DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MMM/yy";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView( R.layout.todo_add_layout);


    mContext = this;
    realm=Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    setUpUIViews();
    showData();

    final String taskId = getIntent().getStringExtra(INTENT_KEY_ID);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (taskId == null)
                addTask();
            else
                editTask(taskId);
        }
    });
    mTaskDateEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            datePicker(view);
        }
    });
    mTaskDateEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (b)
                datePicker(view);
        }
    });
    mTaskTimeEditText.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            timePicker( view );
        }
    } );
    mTaskTimeEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (b)
                timePicker( view );
        }
    });
    if (taskId != null) {
        fillTask(realm.where(TodoModel.class).equalTo("id", taskId).findFirst());
        button.setText("EDIT");
    }



}
private void setUpUIViews() {
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_add_task_bt_add);
    mTaskNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_add_task_et_name);
    mTaskDateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_add_task_et_date);
    mTaskTimeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_add_task_et_time);
}

public void showData(){
     results = realm.where(TodoModel.class).findAll();
}

protected TodoModel getTask(int position) {
    return results.get(position);
}

private void fillTask(TodoModel task) {
    mTaskNameEditText.setText(task.getName());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    mTaskDateEditText.setText(sdf.format(task.getDate()));
    mTaskTimeEditText.setText(task.getTime());
}

private void addTask() {
    String taskName = mTaskNameEditText.getText().toString();
    String taskDate = mTaskDateEditText.getText().toString();
    String taskTime = mTaskTimeEditText.getText().toString();
    if (taskName.length() == 0 || taskName.equals("")) {
        mTaskNameEditText.setError("Should be filled");
        return;
    }
    if (taskDate.length() == 0 || taskDate.equals("")) {
        mTaskDateEditText.setError("Should be filled");
        return;
    }
    TodoModel task = getTask(taskName, taskDate,taskTime);
    if (task == null) {
        mTaskDateEditText.setError("Not a correct date");
        return;
    }
    task.setDone(false);
    addTask(task);
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();
}

protected void addTask(TodoModel task) {

    realm.beginTransaction();
    TodoModel newTask = realm.createObject(TodoModel.class, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    newTask.setName(task.getName());
    newTask.setDate(task.getDate());
    newTask.setTime(task.getTime());
    realm.commitTransaction();

}
private void editTask(String taskId) {
    String taskName = mTaskNameEditText.getText().toString();
    String taskDate = mTaskDateEditText.getText().toString();
    String taskTime = mTaskTimeEditText.getText().toString();
    if (taskName.length() == 0 || taskName.equals("")) {
        mTaskNameEditText.setError("Should be filled");
        return;
    }
    if (taskDate.length() == 0 || taskDate.equals("")) {
        mTaskDateEditText.setError("Should be filled");
        return;
    }
    if (taskTime.length() == 0 || taskTime.equals("")) {
        mTaskTimeEditText.setError("Should be filled");
        return;
    }
    TodoModel task = getTask(taskName, taskDate,taskTime);
    if (task == null) {
        mTaskDateEditText.setError("Not a correct date");
        return;
    }
    task.setId(taskId);
    updateTask(task);
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();
}

protected void updateTask(TodoModel task) {

    realm.beginTransaction();
    TodoModel newTask = realm.where(TodoModel.class).equalTo("id", task.getId()).findFirst();
    newTask.setDate(task.getDate());
    newTask.setDone(task.isDone());
    newTask.setName(task.getName());
    realm.commitTransaction();
}


private void datePicker(final View view) {
    Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = currentTime.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int monthOfYear = currentTime.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dayOfMonth = currentTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, 0, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
            ((EditText) view).setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
        }
    }, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

    mDatePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Time");
    mDatePickerDialog.show();
}
private void timePicker(final View view) {
    Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(mContext,0, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            mTaskTimeEditText.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
        }
    }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
    mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
    mTimePicker.show();

}


private TodoModel getTask(String name, String dateString,String time) {
    TodoModel task = new TodoModel();
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        task.setName(name);
        task.setDate(sdf.parse(dateString));
        task.setTime(time );
        task.setDone(false);
        return task;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
        onBackPressed();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**Adapter class is**

```
    public class TodoAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<TodoModel, TodoAdapter.TaskHolder> {
    public final static String INTENT_KEY_ID = "taskId";
    //public final static String INTENT_KEY_POSITION = "position";
    public final static String DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MMM/yy";

    private Realm realm;

    public interface TaskListener {

    }

    private final TaskListener taskListener;
    private final Context context;

    public TodoAdapter(TaskListener taskListener, RealmResults<TodoModel> realmResults, Context context, Realm realm) {
        super(realmResults, true);
        this.taskListener = taskListener;
        this.context = context;
        this.realm = realm;
    }

    @Override
    public TaskHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new TaskHolder( LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todo_row, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TaskHolder holder, final int position) {
        final TodoModel task = getData().get(position);
        holder.taskTextView.setText(task.getName());
        holder.doneCheckBox.setChecked(task.isDone());
        holder.timeTextView.setText( task.getTime() );
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

        final Date date = (task.getDate());
        if (sdf.format(date).equals(sdf.format(getDate(0))))
            holder.dateTextView.setText("Today");
        else if (sdf.format(date).equals(sdf.format(getDate(-1))))
            holder.dateTextView.setText("Yesterday");
        else if (sdf.format(date).equals(sdf.format(getDate(1))))
            holder.dateTextView.setText("Tomorrow");
        else if (date.getTime() < getDate(6).getTime()) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            holder.dateTextView.setText( DateFormat.format("EEEE", calendar.getTime()).toString());
        } else
            holder.dateTextView.setText(sdf.format(task.getDate()));
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, TodoAddActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra(INTENT_KEY_ID, getTask(position).getId());
                //intent.putExtra(INTENT_KEY_POSITION, position);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.doneCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TodoModel task = new TodoModel();
                task.setId(getTask(position).getId());
                task.setDate(getTask(position).getDate());
                task.setName(getTask(position).getName());
                task.setDone(((CheckBox) v).isChecked());
                updateTask(position, task);
            }
        });

        holder.deleteImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (getTask(position).isDone()) {
                    removeTask(position);
                    return;
                }
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete?");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to delete the task you created?");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        removeTask(position);
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public class TaskHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public CardView cardView;
        public TextView taskTextView;
        public TextView dateTextView;
        public TextView timeTextView;
        public ImageView deleteImageView;
        public CheckBox doneCheckBox;


        public TaskHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            taskTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.row_task_list_tv_name);
            dateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_task_list_tv_date);
            timeTextView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById( R.id.row_task_list_tv_time );
            deleteImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_task_list_iv_delete);
            doneCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_task_list_cb_done);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        }
    }

    private Date getDate(int day) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, day);
        return calendar.getTime();
    }

    protected TodoModel getTask(int position) {
        return getData().get(position);
    }

    protected void updateTask(int position, TodoModel task) {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        TodoModel newTask = realm.where(TodoModel.class).equalTo("id", task.getId()).findFirst();
        newTask.setDate(task.getDate());
        newTask.setDone(task.isDone());
        newTask.setName(task.getName());
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }

    protected void removeTask(int position) {
        TodoModel newTask = realm.where(TodoModel.class).equalTo("id", getTask(position).getId()).findFirst();
        realm.beginTransaction();
        newTask.deleteFromRealm();
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
}
```

**Main Fragment**

```
 public class ToDoListFragment extends Fragment implements TodoAdapter.TaskListener{

    private static final int ADD_TASK_REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
    private static final int EDIT_TASK_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;

    private Realm realm;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TodoAdapter adapter;

    public ToDoListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todo_layout, container, false);

        // Views
        FloatingActionButton addFloatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.activity_tasks_fab_add);
        //Listeners
        addFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(getActivity(), TodoAddActivity.class), ADD_TASK_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_tasks_ll_task);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        setAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }
    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.blu_home).setVisible(true);
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void setAdapter() {

        adapter = new TodoAdapter(this,realm.where(TodoModel.class).findAllSortedAsync("name"),getActivity(), realm);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void setUpRecycler() {

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        setAdapter();
    }
}
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n4yq.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQjHD.png)

**Logcat**

```
09-06 18:49:36.227 3214-3214/demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and, PID: 3214
                                                                          java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Out of range  in /home/cc/repo/realm/release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_Collection.cpp line 152(requested: 1 valid: 1)
                                                                              at io.realm.internal.Collection.nativeGetRow(Native Method)
                                                                              at io.realm.internal.Collection.getUncheckedRow(Collection.java:410)
                                                                              at io.realm.OrderedRealmCollectionImpl.get(OrderedRealmCollectionImpl.java:111)
                                                                              at io.realm.RealmResults.get(RealmResults.java:60)
                                                                              at io.realm.OrderedRealmCollectionImpl.get(OrderedRealmCollectionImpl.java:21)
                                                                              at demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and.adapter.TodoAdapter.getTask(TodoAdapter.java:154)
                                                                              at demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and.adapter.TodoAdapter$3.onClick(TodoAdapter.java:103)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View
```

Comment: @Krupa Could you please have a look in my code and tell me what to do

Comment: Try to update your adapter. For your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31368367/5909385

Comment: @KrupaKakkad I am already using updated adapter compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.1.0'

Comment: @KrupaKakkad I have given my Main Fragment To Do Class From where I am executing to do application

Comment: I am talking about `list.remove(position);
recycler.removeViewAt(position);
mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);                 
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());` Try this

Comment: i am using Realm, and data should be deleted from Realm. That is why I have written  newTask.deleteFromRealm(); but the main problem is in add activity. Bcause when I edit some item, it never stores in correct position, also after deleting one item the whole list become unmanaged

Comment: I have modified my question

Comment: There are about 4 major errors in this code and I'm currently on a phone so I can't rewrite it yet. But you should not have a static List called `tasks` at all.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Please help me to find out the problem. I am still very new in Realm.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TodoAddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Variables
    private Context mContext;

    private Realm realm;
    private TodoModel task;
    private Button button;
    private EditText mTaskNameEditText;
    private EditText mTaskDateEditText;
    private EditText mTaskTimeEditText;
    String time;

    //private static List<TodoModel> tasks;
    private RealmResults<TodoModel> results;

    public final static String INTENT_KEY_ID = "taskId";
    public final static String DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MMM/yy";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView( R.layout.todo_add_layout);

        mContext = this;
        realm=Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        setUpUIViews();
        showData();

        final String taskId = getIntent().getStringExtra(INTENT_KEY_ID);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (taskId == null)
                    addTask();
                else
                    editTask(taskId);
            }
        });
        mTaskDateEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                datePicker(view);
            }
        });
        mTaskDateEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (b)
                    datePicker(view);
            }
        });
        mTaskTimeEditText.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                timePicker( view );
            }
        } );
        mTaskTimeEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (b)
                    timePicker( view );
            }
        });
        if (taskId != null) {
            fillTask(realm.where(TodoModel.class).equalTo("id", taskId).findFirst());
            button.setText("EDIT");
        }

    }
    private void setUpUIViews() {
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_add_task_bt_add);
        mTaskNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_add_task_et_name);
        mTaskDateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_add_task_et_date);
        mTaskTimeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_add_task_et_time);
    }

    public void showData(){
        //tasks = new ArrayList<>(); //error
        //RealmResults<TodoModel> tasksResult = realm.where(TodoModel.class).findAll();
        //for (TodoModel task : tasksResult)
        //    tasks.add(task); //error*/
        results = realm.where(TodoModel.class).findAll();
    }

    protected TodoModel getTask(int position) {
        return results.get(position);
    }

    private void fillTask(TodoModel task) {
        mTaskNameEditText.setText(task.getName());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        mTaskDateEditText.setText(sdf.format(task.getDate()));
        mTaskTimeEditText.setText(task.getTime());
    }

    private void addTask() {
        String taskName = mTaskNameEditText.getText().toString();
        String taskDate = mTaskDateEditText.getText().toString();
        String taskTime = mTaskTimeEditText.getText().toString();
        if (taskName.length() == 0 || taskName.equals("")) {
            mTaskNameEditText.setError("Should be filled");
            return;
        }
        if (taskDate.length() == 0 || taskDate.equals("")) {
            mTaskDateEditText.setError("Should be filled");
            return;
        }
        TodoModel task = getTask(taskName, taskDate,taskTime);
        if (task == null) {
            mTaskDateEditText.setError("Not a correct date");
            return;
        }
        task.setDone(false);
        addTask(task);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }

    protected void addTask(TodoModel task) {

        realm.beginTransaction();
        TodoModel newTask = realm.createObject(TodoModel.class, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        newTask.setName(task.getName());
        newTask.setDate(task.getDate());
        newTask.setTime(task.getTime());
        //realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(newTask);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        //realm.close();
    }
    private void editTask(String taskId) {
        String taskName = mTaskNameEditText.getText().toString();
        String taskDate = mTaskDateEditText.getText().toString();
        String taskTime = mTaskTimeEditText.getText().toString();
        if (taskName.length() == 0 || taskName.equals("")) {
            mTaskNameEditText.setError("Should be filled");
            return;
        }
        if (taskDate.length() == 0 || taskDate.equals("")) {
            mTaskDateEditText.setError("Should be filled");
            return;
        }
        if (taskTime.length() == 0 || taskTime.equals("")) {
            mTaskTimeEditText.setError("Should be filled");
            return;
        }
        TodoModel task = getTask(taskName, taskDate,taskTime);
        if (task == null) {
            mTaskDateEditText.setError("Not a correct date");
            return;
        }
        task.setId(taskId);
        updateTask(task);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }

    protected void updateTask(TodoModel task) {

        realm.beginTransaction();
        TodoModel newTask = realm.where(TodoModel.class).equalTo("id", task.getId()).findFirst();
        newTask.setDate(task.getDate());
        newTask.setDone(task.isDone());
        newTask.setName(task.getName());
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }


    private void datePicker(final View view) {
        Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = currentTime.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int monthOfYear = currentTime.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dayOfMonth = currentTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, 0, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
                ((EditText) view).setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
            }
        }, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        mDatePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Time");
        mDatePickerDialog.show();
    }
    private void timePicker(final View view) {
        Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(mContext,0, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                mTaskTimeEditText.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
            }
        }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
        mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
        mTimePicker.show();

    }


    private TodoModel getTask(String name, String dateString,String time) {
        TodoModel task = new TodoModel();
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
            task.setName(name);
            task.setDate(sdf.parse(dateString));
            task.setTime(time );
            task.setDone(false);
            return task;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
            onBackPressed();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: where you initialize editTask(taskId); taskId is showing error

Comment: taskId Error:(79, 30) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

Comment: Be more specific

Comment: editTask(taskId); ths line in oncreate method is showing error. Error:(79, 30) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. you have initialize it  final String taskId = getIntent().getStringExtra(INTENT_KEY_ID);

Comment: Bah. My phone really did have a half-complete copy of the code I was editing.

Comment: Is that a misatake?

Comment: That's because on the other side that sends the intent, you're still sending the position instead of task id, so you get a type mismatch in Bundle which results in a log message and the `getStringExtra` method returning  `null` each time

Comment: This is a completely different question at this point, I recommend reading about using intents to communicate and send parameters to other activities https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent

Comment: You ***don't want to send position here***.

Comment: I know, it might be too much irritating for you. I thank you very much that you spend time to give my answer. Your answer solved my problem paertially, I change the adaprer class also, there i sent id instead of position.  Now at the end whole problem is same as before. I creare 3 or 4 list, kije task 1, task2, task3.. and then when I click on task1 and try to edit and store. after that when I click one iteem it nver shows the correct one. May be task 2 or task3. The same problem, but never solved. Also if I select 1 item it selects two at a time :(