# How to update adapter items in previous activity in stack when user presses the back button?

Tags: android, android-activity, redux

I have a RecyclerView list, and an items passes to it's adapter. Now when I click a row in this list, it will show the details of the pressed item.

Let's say I need to toggle the selected item as `liked` or `disliked`, as each item in the dataset will have `isLiked` property with either `true` or `false` value.

Now if I changed the `isLiked` value from false to true, I need to reflect the same change to the recyclerview in the parent - or the previous activity in the stack.

User will click 'back' from device and back to the list. But the changes made in the details activity is not reflecting on the previous list.

I was thinking of using `Redux` for state management, but not sure what is the ideal solution for this issue.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Use event bus for this Any problem paste the code 
take refrence
http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/

First you need Pojo to get Notified suppose

```
public class NewsCategoryEvent extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    String selectedCategory;
    boolean isSelected;

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

    public String getSelectedCategory() {
        return selectedCategory;
    }

    public void setSelectedCategory(String selectedCategory) {
        this.selectedCategory = selectedCategory;
    }
}
```

Then Notify EventBus after making changes in your activity in any method as:

```
      //newsCategoryEvent is object of your pojo 
      NewsCategoryEvent selectedNewsCategoryEvent = new NewsCategoryEvent ();
      newsCategoryEvent.setSelected(true);
    EventBus.getDefault().post(newsCategoryEvent);
```

When you back pressed you need to register and notify changes in your 
 First Register your Eventbus in onStart();

```
  @Override
    protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart()
       EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }
```

Outside onCreate(): notifed recyclar view is updated

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onMessageEvent(NewsCategory event) {
        newsListRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and in onStop() unregister EventBus as

```
@Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in documentation they mention: ```
@Override
    public void onStop() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onStop();
    }
```

If I unregistered it from parent activity it will not get notified.

And if I disabled the unregister call, whenever I fire an action, let's say I fired it the third time, the subscriber will be called 3 times. Do you advise for solution?

Comment: Check out the code and also paste your code such that i can help you more

Comment: Didn't you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31368367/5166080), you need to call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after you return from your "detail view", whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your recycler view catch up changes you do on your details screen, 
be sure you have correctly defined DiffCallback on your recycler view so that isLike has been checked.

For example if you have you DiffCallback like:

```
class YourListAdapter : PagedListAdapter<YourItem, YourViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {



    companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<YourItem>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: YourItem, newItem: YourItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: YourItem, newItem: YourItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id && oldItem.isLike == newItem.isLike
        }
    }
}
```