# RecyclerView scroll returning to the top of the list when add new items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm developing a application that the RecyclerView load new data when the user hit the bottom of the scroll. However, the list is already completed and have it's fixed size, I just want to put the content in the Recycler, but when I insert the content in the Recycler, the scroll returns to the top of the list. And then I need to scroll down all over again until I reach the new data that was inserted in to the bottom of the list. All that I want is to maintain the scroll position when the new data is loaded.

I've tried use descendantFocusability = "blocksDescendants", but this didn't work.

This is my XML code where the RecyclerView can be found

```xml
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:headerLayout="@layout/top_navigation_bar"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/productsLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#EBE7E7"
>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/productsLayoutTitle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
android:text="@string/produtos_em_destaque"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textStyle="normal"/>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/productsLayoutTitle"
/>

<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressBar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/recyclerView"
android:scaleX="1"
android:scaleY="1"
android:progressTint="#1C36FF"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code that is used to add data to the RecyclersView is

```
fun showData(products:Product,productsListSize:Int){

if(!isStarted){

  recyclerView.apply{
   layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
   adapter=ViewHolderAdapter(products,productsListSize)
   (adapter as ViewHolderAdapter).notifyItemRangeInserted(0,productsListSize)
   pageNumber++
  }

  progressBar.visibility=View.GONE
  isStarted=true
}else{

  recyclerView.apply{
    adapter=ViewHolderAdapter(products,pageNumber*limitPerPage)
    (adapter as ViewHolderAdapter).notifyItemRangeInserted(((pageNumber-1)*limitPerPage),pageNumber*limitPerPage)
    pageNumber++
  }
  progressBar.visibility=View.GONE
}

}
```

My ViewHolderAdapter

```
packagecom.example.kotlinbasics

importandroid.graphics.Color
importandroid.view.LayoutInflater
importandroid.view.View
importandroid.view.ViewGroup
importandroid.widget.ImageView
importandroid.widget.RatingBar
importandroid.widget.TextView
importandroidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
importcom.squareup.picasso.Picasso
importkotlinx.android.synthetic.main.recyclerview_layout.view.*

class ViewHolderAdapter(private val products:Product,private val productsListSize:Int):RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolderAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent:ViewGroup,viewType:Int):ViewHolder{
val view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_layout,parent,false)
return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount()=productsListSize

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder:ViewHolder,position:Int){

holder.productName.text=products.produtos[position].nome
Picasso.get().load(products.produtos[position].img).into(holder.productImage)
}

class ViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

val productName:TextView=itemView.ProductName
val productImage:ImageView=itemView.ProductImage
}

}
```

All application works really fine, the only problem is with that scroll behavior.
I expected that the scroll position didn't goes to the top of the RecyclersView list when I add new data in him.

Comment: This is caused by replacing adapter when data changes. You're only supposed to update the list it references and notify changes.

Comment: You are creating a new adapter and set it to the RecyclerView every time, no wonder it will jump to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are creating a new adapter each time, the `RecyclerView` will be always going back to the start position. You have to update the current adapter, and not to create another adapter with the entire list.

You should have a method on your adapter to manage the item list, such as

```
fun updateList(product: Product) {
    myList.add(product.list)
}
```

And in your else branch you will need to update the list

```
recyclerView.apply{
    (adapter as? ViewHolderAdapter)?.updateList(products)
}
```

Comment: Hi Diego, first of all, thank you for helping me, you're the guy.

I'm a beginner in Kotlin, so can you explain a little bit more detailed? I'll be very grateful.

Comment: I am not able to provide more code because I don't have your `ViewHolderAdapter` code. But the main point is that you should keep the same adapter and only update the data. You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data?rq=1) helpful in how to achieve this.

Comment: I edited and add the ViewHolderAdapter. He's pretty simple

Comment: I think that my case is a little different of the link that you recommend me, because I do not use Lists inside my ViewHolderAdapter

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. You will need a list in your `ViewHolderAdapter`. The adapter will receive additional elements to append to its list to allow the `RecyclerView` to maintain the current position.

Comment: Valeu cara. Foi isso mesmo. Muito obrigado

Comment: Nice! Also, be sure to use English in your comments.

Answer (score 1):

just use code bellow, and input requared position (in your case - last position)
recyclerView.scrollToPosition()

Answer (score 1):

Create one instance of your recycler view adapter , the pass the orignal list to it . whenever you want to add the any data , add it to the list , and then notify the adapter. 
In your case , Just add the product list and notify it

```
private list<product> list = newArrayList<>();

adapter= new ViewHolderAdapter(list);
```

OnClick of button when you want to add data , just insert it into the list

```
list.addAll(productlist);
And now notify it to the adapter 
adapter.notifyDataSetChange();
```

In your case

```
fun showData(products:Product,productsListSize:Int){

if(!isStarted){

         list.addAll(product)
          adapter.notifyDataSetChange();
          pageNumber++
    }

         progressBar.visibility=View.GONE
         isStarted=true
    }
    progressBar.visibility=View.GONE
 }

     }
```

Comment: I understand your point, but in my case, the list is already completed, I don't need to add nothing in the product's list. I just want to show the content in pages when the user scroll.