# Horizontal Recyclerview: setting custom item width is creating issues

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

Dont know whether there's an issue with my code or the recyclerview itself, but whenever I'm trying to populate a new list to the recyclerview, it auto scrolls itself to the top of the index. This does not happen when I set the items' width to MATCH PARENT, only if I am setting a custom width to the itemviews, this strange bug happens.I also tried using notifyItemRangeChanged or notifyItemChanged, but unfortunately nothing seems to work.

```
val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
recyclerViewSubscriptions.layoutManager = layoutManager
recyclerViewSubscriptions.adapter = subscriptionAdapter
subscriptionAdapter?.setData(subscriptionList, true, null, false)
```

Adapter setData code:

```
fun setData(
    users: MutableList<SubscribtionListItem>?,
    hideButtons: Boolean,
    activeSubscriptionType: Int?,
    isPendingRequest: Boolean,
    isPlanReplaced: Boolean = false,
    standardPlanDuration: Int = 0
) {
    this.subscribtionListItem = users
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56465852/11880323 don't create an adapter everytime

Comment: @cmak Iam not creating a new adapter each time,,,I'm just updating the data..I also tried notifyItemChanged but still this peculiar issue persists.

Also as mentioned if I remove the custom width and set the itemview's parent width to MATCH_PARENT then this issues does not occur

Comment: Try updating the existing list instead of setting new one

Comment: @cmak tried the same..also played around with notifyItemRangeChange and notifyItemIndex..still the issue persists

Comment: What about overriding `getItemId`?

Comment: @cmak yes and issue is still the same. Also, Im reiterating that  if I remove the custom width and set the itemview's parent width to MATCH_PARENT then this issues does not occur...hence this should not be a concern of item id I suppose