# Push value received from socket to RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I've the below code that was working fine with `RecyclerView`, in the same time, I've a `websocket` that works for `onMessage` and print the received msg correctly.

Then I tried to merge them together, i.e. receive data from `socket` and push it directly to the `RecyclerView` but it is not showing anything in `RecyclerView` screen

During one of my trials, I got this error:

> I/Websocket: Error Only the original thread that created a view
>   hierarchy can touch its views.

```
lateinit var mWebSocketClient: WebSocketClient
lateinit var uniqueID: String
lateinit var rv: RecyclerView

val chaptersList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        rv = rvChapterList    //  "@+id/rvChapterList" of RecyclerView

         // chaptersList.add(s)
         //   rvChapterList.layoutManager = layoutManager
         //   rvChapterList.adapter = ChapterAdapter(this, chaptersList)
        var context= this
        connectWebSocket(context)
}


fun connectWebSocket(context: MainActivity) {
    val uri: URI
    try {
        uri = URI("ws://10.0.2.2:8080/ws")
    } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        println("ws faild")
        return
    }

    mWebSocketClient = object : WebSocketClient(uri) {
        override fun onOpen(serverHandshake: ServerHandshake) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Opened")
            mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL)
        }

        override fun onMessage(s: String) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Recieved $s")  // This is working
            chaptersList.add(s)
            Log.i("chaptersList", "chaptersList $s")  // This is working

            rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            rv.adapter = ChapterAdapter(context , chaptersList)  // This is not working

        }
    }
    mWebSocketClient.connect()
}
```

**UPDATE**

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48959184/2441637) answer, I tried the below, but it did not work:

```
lateinit var rv: RecyclerView
lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
lateinit var adaptor: ChapterAdapter

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            rv = rvChapterList
            adaptor = ChapterAdapter(this, chaptersList)
           rv.adapter = adaptor
           rv.layoutManager = layoutManager
           rv.adapter = ChapterAdapter(this, chaptersList)
    }
}

fun connectWebSocket(context: MainActivity) {
   override fun onMessage(s: String) {
            val insertIndex = chaptersList.size
            chaptersList.add(insertIndex, s)
            adaptor.notifyItemInserted(insertIndex)

            adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views can be reached only within *main thread*. As `onMessage()` method runs on *worker thread (background)*, it cannot make changes on view directly. There are several ways to make changes on views from *worker thread* like `androd.os.Handler`. In your case `runOnUiThread(Runnable)` method, which is provided by `Activity.class`, is a good choice. It takes `runnable` as an argument and runs it on UI thread. In your case it can be used as following:

```
override fun onMessage(s: String) {
    val insertIndex = chaptersList.size
    chaptersList.add(insertIndex, s)

    Thread {
        runOnUiThread {
            adaptor.notifyItemInserted(insertIndex)  
        }
    }.run()
}
```

**Update:**
Another more reliable way is using [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) from [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture). As `LiveData` is an observable and lifecycle-aware data holder class, it can be used like this:

Another class file:

```
class SocketClient {
    val message = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun connectWebSocket(context: Context) {
        // Setup stuff

        mWebSocketClient = object : WebSocketClient(uri) {
            override fun onOpen(serverHandshake: ServerHandshake) {
                // Opened do some stuff
            }

            override fun onMessage(s: String) {
                message.postValue(s)
            }
        }
        mWebSocketClient.connect()
    }
}
```

And within activity's `onCreate()`:

```
val client = SocketClient()

client.message.observe(this, Observer { s: String ->
    val insertIndex = chaptersList.size
    chaptersList.add(insertIndex, s)
    adaptor.notifyItemInserted(insertIndex)
})

client.connectWebSocket(this)
```

Before using `LiveData`, it is required to add dependencies. See [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle).
as:

```
    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is if `connectWebSocket()` is running within the `MainActivity` scope, but if it is running outside it, I get that I need to define the `runOnUiThread` function, what can I do in this case?

Comment: Updated my post @HasanAYousef