# How do I update my RecyclerView button state on click after alert dialog confirmation in activity/fragment?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-recyclerview

I have a pretty unique situation, where I have a button in a recyclerview, which upon click (initial state "register"), passes an intent to a broadcast receiver in fragment or activity where it throws an alert dialog , with 2 options, yes or no. If no is selected, nothing happens and the dialog dismisses, but if yes is clicked, it processes a function I defined in my presenter class (related to data) and is supposed to update my button ui state to "cancel". and same goes for the other way around where upon clicking cancel it will bring back alert, and clicking on yes will switch the ui text to register.

Now I have implemented the code as follows.(please note, even notifydatasetchanged doesnt work for me). Any idea what I am doing wrong and how I can achieve this?
code in my `public void onBind(int position)` function in adapter:

```java
if (repo.getIsRsvpAvailable().equals("true")) {
    rsvpButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    for (int i = 0; i < mAllRSVPEventsList.size(); i++) {
        if (mAllRSVPEventsList.get(i).getEvent().getEventId().equals(repo.getEventId()) && mAllRSVPEventsList.get(i).getIsAttending()) {
            rsvpButton.setText("CANCEL");
            rsvpButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent in = new Intent("main_rsvp_button_clicked");
                in.putExtra("main_rsvp_event_id", repo.getEventId());
                in.putExtra("main_rsvp_is_attending", "false");
                in.putExtra("main_rsvp_item_position", position);
                rsvpButton.getContext().sendBroadcast(in);
            });
            break;
        } else {
            rsvpButton.setText("RSVP");
            rsvpButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent in = new Intent("main_rsvp_button_clicked");
                in.putExtra("main_rsvp_event_id", repo.getEventId());
                in.putExtra("main_rsvp_is_attending", "true");
                in.putExtra("main_rsvp_item_position", position);

                rsvpButton.getContext().sendBroadcast(in);
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the corresponding code in broadcast receiver in my activity :

```java
private BroadcastReceiver mEventIdReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            String eventId = intent.getStringExtra(EVENTID_MAIN_EXTRA_TITLE);
            String isAttending = intent.getStringExtra(EVENTID_MAIN_IS_ATTENDING);
            int itemPosition = intent.getIntExtra(EVENTID_MAIN_RSVP_ITEM_POSITION, 0);


            if (isAttending.equals("true")) {
                showDialog(R.string.rsvp_title, R.string.confirm_rsvp_body, R.string.yes,
                        (dialog, which) -> {
                            mPresenter.onRSVPClick(eventId, isAttending);

                            mEventListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            mEventRecyclerView.removeAllViews();
                            mEventRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(itemPosition);

                        }, R.string.no, null, null);
            } else {
                showDialog(R.string.rsvp_title, R.string.confirm_cancel_body, R.string.yes,
                        (dialog, which) -> {
                            mPresenter.onRSVPClick(eventId, isAttending);

                            mEventListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            mEventRecyclerView.removeAllViews();
                            mEventRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(itemPosition);

                        }, R.string.no, null, null);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Please note: mEventListAdapter is my adapter i am using the button UI code in and mEventRecyclerView is the recycler view i am using in the fragment.

Any idea what I am missing or doing wrong?
Thanks!

RSVPClick method :

```java
@Override
public void onRSVPClick(String eventId, String isAttending) {
    getMvpView().showLoading();
    getCompositeDisposable().add(getDataManager()
            .doRSVPEventApiCall(
                    eventId,
                    getDataManager().getFirstName(),
                    getDataManager().getLastName(),
                    getDataManager().getCurrentUserEmail(),
                    isAttending
            )
            .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
            .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
            .subscribe(response -> {
                if (!isViewAttached()) {
                    return;
                }
                getMvpView().hideLoading();
            }, throwable -> {
                if (!isViewAttached()) {
                    return;
                }
                getMvpView().hideLoading();
                if (throwable instanceof ANError) {
                    ANError anError = (ANError) throwable;
                    handleApiError(anError);
                }
            }));
}
```

Comment: why do you use the onbindviewholder method instead of oncreateviewholder to create listeners? You did not forget to subscribe to broadcast receiver?

Comment: I do subscribe to broadcast receiver, it only works sometimes but doesnt often for some reason

Comment: Try to use `mEventListAdapter.notifyItemChanged(itemPosition)` instead of `mEventListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, @AngelaHeely

Comment: tried that too :( ,no luck

Comment: Can you show the onRSVPClick method and adapter?

Comment: i have added it to my question now., its in presenter class and called in activity broadcast receiver

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE]." See also [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: This may sound not very encouraging but the point is that I need that "shortest code necessary to reproduce" the issue in order to help you. I'm sure it's possible and I have some ideas what might be wrong but I'd like to make sure by running the problem code in my IDE. So if the others can't help you maybe you'd like to take the time and add the missing pieces

Comment: if you can provide an example project using recyclerview using buttons in its items and an adapter where the button UI is set, clicking on which sends an intent to the broadcast receiver which changes its state upon clicking alert would be as simple as it would get. If you can create a small and simple project and demo it works, that will be a great help.I can definitely refactor my code around it

Comment: I am not sure why you need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` to solve this problem, an  `interface` can definitely solve the communication problem. As for changing the UI button on alert dialog action, you should store a meta-data of each view in the recycler view, this metadata should tell if the current view needs to be changed or not. I am just giving an overall suggestion.

Comment: i am definitely open to updates and suggestions. Can you explain with code for my scenario.That'll definitely help

Answer (score 2):

Are you updating the **repo** object based on user selected action on the dialog before calling `notifyDatasetChanged()`?
Looks like the `doRSVPEventApiCall()` method does not update the list of items available to the adapter thus `notifyDatasetChanged()` has no effect.

Comment: it might take a few seconds to update. but regardless of whether it updates or not, is it possible to change the ui of the button in adapter to a different state (say cancel from rsvp) once alert appears and yes is clicked

Comment: i assume the object is updated based on the response of the api call. you could update the object state directly and call notifyDatasetChanged. when the api response is received and the state is not same as already updated, you can change it and call notifyDatasetChanged to reflect it.

Comment: i tried everything, but not sure what is missing. is there a sample app you can point me too where a similar scenario works as expected?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily maintain an array to indicate the state of the buttons of each of your items in the `RecyclerView`. For example, let us assume there are two states of each button (i.e RSVP = 0, Cancel = 1). Now declare an array in your `RecyclerView` adapter like the following.

```
private int[] stateArray;
```

In the constructor of your adapter, initialize the array like the following. Let us assume your constructor looks like the following.

```
public EventListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Event> eventList) {
    this.eventList = eventList; 
    stateArray = new int[eventList.size];
    initializeTheStateArray(eventList);
}

private void initializeTheStateArray(ArrayList<Event> eventList) {

    // Initialize the array so that we can keep track of the items which are being attended or not. 
    for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) {
        if(event.isAttending()) stateArray[i] = 1;
        else stateArray[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Now in the `onBindViewHolder` function, set the text of the button based on the entry of the `stateArray`. This should look somewhat like the following.

```
if(stateArray[position] == 1) button.setText("Cancel"); // Because this item is already registerd 
else button.setText("RSVP");
```

You need some additional function in your adapter so that you can update the `stateArray` on your button click or from an update from the API.

```
public void updateButtonState(int position, boolean isAttendening) {
    if(isAttending) stateArray[position] = 1;
    else stateArray[position] = 0;
    notifyDataSetChanged(); // Call the notifyDataSetChanged here to see the affect
}
```

And when you update the whole list of your adapter after an API call, do not forget the update the `stateArray` as well. I hope you have a function to update the event list in your adapter already. Modify the function like the following.

```
public void updateEventList(ArrayList<Event> eventList) {
    this.eventList = eventList;
    stateArray = new int[eventList.size()];
    initializeTheStateArray(eventList);
}
```

Now you can call `updateButtonState` function of your adapter when the button is clicked. Modify the button click action in your `rsvpButton.setOnClickListener`.

You can also modify the `onReceive` function if necessary to get the expected output in your `RecyclerView`.

Hope this setup will help you to achieve the expected behavior that you want.

Last, but not least, in your `onReceive` function, you are immediately updating the `RecyclerView` when it will have no effect on the items of the `RecyclerView` because the network call is asynchronous and will take some time to fetch the data from the API. You might consider calling the `updateEventList` method from the `onRSVPClick` method when the data is available from the API call.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is a little difficult to do, as I have 2 different api endpoints, 1 returns the entire event list, without information about rsvp (is attending), another one gives only the list of events where isattending is true. so i have to make 2 different api calls, so combinging them is a bit difficult in presenter, i can paste code for all my classes if that helps understand my issue better.  i will add the links to the 3 classes shortly for better understanding the issue

Comment: This is a link to corresponding fragment : https://pastebin.com/rSNQny5U   (please note, i m not using broadcast receiver anymore, code is commented out there,instead i m using interface)

Comment: Finally here's the presenter : https://pastebin.com/2Wtpp6g7 . please note, the onViewPrepared has the 2 different endpoint calls I am getting the data from (get requests) and onRSVPClick is where i m posting my response on button click (as rsvp true or false ). Hope this makes it clearer

Comment: also, I have 2 interfaces for the MVP pattern, where eventlistmvpview has 3 function declarations : void updateRepo(List<EventListResponse.Repo> repoList);
    void updateRSVP(List<AllRSVPEvents.Event> rsvpList);
    void setEvents(List<AllRSVPEvents.Event> eventList);

Comment: and EventListMvpPresenter which has void onViewPrepared();
    void onRSVPClick(String eventId, String isAttending);  declarations

Comment: Sorry, I had to post in different comments, as I didnt want it to be confusing. Basically, these are the only classes I use, not sure where the disconnect is, but I believe once i get the updated response of events , I would like to update the ui button from rsvp to cancel or vice versa. not sure how to modify your above code to meet my criteria, but would really appreciate any help! thanks so much!

Comment: Hey, I will try to look into those codes as soon as I can manage some time. Thank you for your comments for making things clearer. :)

Comment: thank you! I appreciate your time! Been struggling with this issue for a while, I wonder if there was atleast a way in which upon refreshing the list, i can send back the user to the same tile, when i do that with recyclerview, it crashes (say with smoothscrolltoposition, since the whole list is recreated i believe)

Comment: I have a feeling I might not be comparing the results correctly in adapter, which is why its not accurately updating data. (for rsvp button for loop block in adapter). hope that makes sense. I have 2 set of lists returned by both endpoints, i m trying to compare 1 with another

Comment: Thanks for the help/ I will award you the bounty, since you tried to help with the most detailed answer! I appreciate it

Comment: Great to know that you could solve that problem! I am sorry that I could not manage to look into your code in the meantime as I am traveling. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I think that perhaps this might help:

1. Set click listener on the button in `onBindViewHolder()`.
2. Inside your click listener call `notifyItemChanged(position)`
3. Maintain some state in your adapter to handle the logic for when to change the buttons state, for instance, have a var in the onClick you can flag like `shouldChangeState = true`
4. When on `onBindViewHolder()` is called again, check this state and bind as you would usually only handle this scenario and change TextView accordingly. `button.setVisibility(..)` or `button.text = "My New Text"`

Inside onBindViewholder :

```
 holder.myRow.setOnClickListener(v -> {
          notifyItemChanged(position) 
 }
```

Ok, so to handle your holder inside your onBindViewHolder (In Kotlin Sorry):

Create your view holder.

```
sealed class MyListViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)

class MyListItemViewHolder(view: View) : MyListViewHolder(view) {
    val name: TextView = view.my_name
    val myDetail: TextView = view.my_detail
    val myOtherDetail: TextView = view.my_other_detail
}
```

In on create:

```
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyListViewHolder {
        val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false)
        val viewHolder = MyListItemViewHolder(view)

        with(view) {
            tag = viewHolder
        }
        return viewHolder
    }
```

Then in onBindViewHolder:

```
  override fun onBindViewHolder(itemHolder: MyListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val holder = itemHolder as MyListItemViewHolder
        val currentInfo = myList[position]

        // Get your data from list to bind here.

        holder.name.text = // Text
        holder.myDetail.text = // Text
        holder.myOtherDetail.text = Text

        holder.setOnClickListener {
             // Other stuff, state, actions etc.
             notifyItemChanged(position)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! The issue I have is my bindviewholder is called outside the viewholder function.Inside viewholder I am calling onBind and declaring the params, so it's restricted within the viewholder. To avoid any confusion, I have posted all my class files in one of the answer by Reaz below (in comments). Let me know if that clears things up a little

Comment: OK, best practice I would say to move it. I will update the answer here in a few.

Comment: I have a feeling I might not be comparing the results correctly in adapter, which is why its not accurately updating data. (for rsvp button for loop block in adapter). hope that makes sense. I have 2 set of lists returned by both endpoints, i m trying to compare 1 with another

Comment: Ah, you can use a biFunction observer, then compare the results there.

Comment: Probably you want to do that in your viewmodel though.

Comment: I dont have a view model. how do i go about it?

Comment: Add one boolean field isProcessingAction in view holder, update it's state on click button ,get its state in onbindviewholder and update buttons state to be hide/visible or if single button is used chnag the text accordingly.

Comment: Looks like you have a Presenter, same kinda functionality.

Answer (score 1):

`notifyDatasetChanged()` should be called after the data set is actually changed. As Sudhanshu Gupta pointed out `notifyDatasetChanged()` is called at the wrong time (when the dialog button is clicked). Since your `mEventListResponseList` and `mAllRSVPEventsList` in the adapter are private the only way to change them is to call `addItems()` and `addRSVPItems()` methods. Clearly at the time of dialog button click, none of these methods are called indicating data set is not changed. So `notifyDatasetChanged()` has no effect.

> it might take a few seconds to update. but regardless of whether it updates or not, is it possible to change the ui of the button in adapter to a different state (say cancel from rsvp) once alert appears and yes is clicked

No, because of the above reason.

And, when the response arrives it is discarded except for logging. Snippet from `onRSVPClick()` in the Presenter class.

```
.subscribe(response -> {
    if (!isViewAttached()) {
        return;
    }
    Log.d("rsvptest", "basic event id:" + response);

    getMvpView().hideLoading();

}
```

To see the change, you should somehow update `mEventListResponseList` and `mAllRSVPEventsList` in the adapter by exposing a suitable method and call it with the data from the arrived response. Also don't forget to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` in that method too.

Comment: any idea about this once : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598276/how-do-i-pass-a-multi-part-body-parameter-for-rxjava2-androidnetworking-post-req