# The notifyDataSetChanged method does no update the RecyclerView layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have created a nested RecyclerView. I fetch data from firebase, then I insert it into one RecyclerView which uses another RecyclerView. In my fragment the code is:

```
    private Map<Character,List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> carsDocuments;
    private DocumentReference connectedGroupDocumentRef;

    private RecyclerView carsRecyclerViewCards;
    private CarDetailsCardAdapter cardsAdapter;

    private View fragmentView;

    public CarsDetailsFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cars_details, container, false);

        // On add new car click
        FloatingActionButton addNewCarFab = (FloatingActionButton) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.fab_add_new_car);
        addNewCarFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddNewCar.class);
                fragmentView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        carsDocuments = new HashMap<>();
        carsRecyclerViewCards = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.rv_car_details_cards);
        connectedGroupDocumentRef = getConnectedGroupReference();
        connectedGroupDocumentRef.collection("cars").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    RelativeLayout emptyView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.cars_details_empty_view);
                    if (task.getResult() == null || task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                        emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        carsRecyclerViewCards.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            char letter = getFirstLetter(document.getString("type"));
                            List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> carsList = carsDocuments.get(letter);
                            if (carsList == null) {
                                carsList = new ArrayList<>();
                                carsList.add(document);
                                carsDocuments.put(letter, carsList);
                            } else {
                                carsList.add(document);
                            }
                        }
                        emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        carsRecyclerViewCards.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        cardsAdapter = new CarsCardAdapter(getActivity(), carsDocuments);
                        carsRecyclerViewCards.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                        carsRecyclerViewCards.setAdapter(cardsAdapter);
                        setRecyclerViewListener();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void setRecyclerViewListener() {
          connectedGroupDocumentRef.collection("cars").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "addSnapshotListener:failure", e);
                    return;
                }

                carsDocuments.clear();
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : value) {
                    char letter = getFirstLetter(document.getString("full_name"));
                    List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> carsList = carsDocuments.get(letter);
                    if (carsList == null) {
                        carsList = new ArrayList<>();
                        carsList.add(document);
                        carsDocuments.put(letter, carsList);
                    } else {
                        carsList.add(document);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("I'm HERE");
                cardsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //carsRecyclerViewCards.invalidate(); 
            }
        });
    }
```

In the `CarsCardAdapter` class:

```
public class CarsCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CarsCardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Map<Character, List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> carsDocuments;
    private Character[] carsLetters;
    private Activity activity;

    private UsersAdapter adapterMember;

    public class ViewHolder extends androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textLetter;
        private RecyclerView recyclerViewUsers;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textLetter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cars_details_letter);
            recyclerViewUsers = itemView.findViewById(R.id.car_details_users);
        }
    }

    CarsCardAdapter(Activity activity, Map<Character,List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> carsDocuments) {
        this.activity = activity;
        if (carsDocuments != null) {
            this.carsDocuments = carsDocuments;
            this.carsLetters = carsDocuments.keySet().toArray(new Character[0]);
        }
    }

    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_car_cards, parent, false));
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final char letter = this.carsLetters[position];
        final List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> carsList = carsDocuments.get(letter);
        holder.textLetter.setText(String.valueOf(letter));
        adapterMember = new UsersAdapter(activity,carsList);
        holder.recyclerViewUsers.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.activity));
        holder.recyclerViewUsers.setAdapter(this.adapterMember);
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.carsLetters.length;
    }
}
```

And the important method is `setRecyclerViewListener` which updates the RecyclerView once the database collection is changed.
As you can see I remove the `carsDocuments` and insert all of the reports. Then I update the adapter by calling `notifyDataSetChanged`. Also tried `invalidate`. 
I know for sure that I get into the listener because `I'm HERE` is printed to the log. Also note that `documentRef.collection("cars").get()...` is being executed in the `onCreateView` of the my fragment. the What could be the issue?

Comment: add    carsList to your adapter before calling notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Jason Hi, why? In this topic: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-dat) they say that I need to just use `clear` and then `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: Can you post the full codes? Activity and adapter

Comment: @Jason I have added the fragment. Do you also need the inner adapter `UsersAdapter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, add this:

```
carsRecyclerViewCards.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cardsAdapter = new CarsCardAdapter(getActivity(), carsDocuments);
                    carsRecyclerViewCards.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                    carsRecyclerViewCards.setAdapter(cardsAdapter);
```

Inside your   setRecyclerViewListener(); like u did in the addOnSuccessListener

Then delete this:

```
   connectedGroupDocumentRef.collection("cars").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                RelativeLayout emptyView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.cars_details_empty_view);
                if (task.getResult() == null || task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                    emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    carsRecyclerViewCards.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        char letter = getFirstLetter(document.getString("type"));
                        List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> carsList = carsDocuments.get(letter);
                        if (carsList == null) {
                            carsList = new ArrayList<>();
                            carsList.add(document);
                            carsDocuments.put(letter, carsList);
                        } else {
                            carsList.add(document);
                        }
                    }
                    emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    carsRecyclerViewCards.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cardsAdapter = new CarsCardAdapter(getActivity(), carsDocuments);
                    carsRecyclerViewCards.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                    carsRecyclerViewCards.setAdapter(cardsAdapter);
                    setRecyclerViewListener();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And put this

```
 setRecyclerViewListener();
```

In its place in onCreate

Comment: You are the best! One question if you may - if I remove some user, the order of the letters is not alphabetically. Do you know maybe why and how to fix it?

Comment: No I don't know why, maybe you should post another question about that. If this answer worked, pls mark it as accepted for future reference