# Recycler view not updating automatically with live data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

My observer is working and it's getting called whenever a new record is entered,

The problem is with recycler view is only showing one record to begin with and it never updates itself to show additional records as a result of save setClickListener.

I can verify in the my database (Room with LiveData) that I've more than one record, there's some problem with the Adapter or the ViewHolder.

**P.S.** Plus any modifications to how things should be done when it comes to patterns with adapter are most welcome. I hope I got it right.

**MainActivity onCreate method**

```
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(BookViewModel::class.java)

    save.setOnClickListener {
        val book = Book(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "author 2", "book 2")
        viewModel.insert(book)
    }

    val bookListAdapter = BookListAdapter(this)
    recyclerView.adapter = bookListAdapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    viewModel.allBooks.observe(this, Observer { books ->
        books?.let {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: changed")
            bookListAdapter.setBooks(books)
        }
    })
```

**static classes in MainActivity**

```
private class BookListAdapter(private val context: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<BookListAdapter.BookViewHolder>() {

    private var bookList: List<Book> = mutableListOf()

    // getting called only once
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BookListAdapter.BookViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return BookViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BookListAdapter.BookViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val book = bookList[position]
        holder.setData(book.author, book.book, position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        Log.d("inner", "getItemCount: ${bookList.size}") // this return correct size
        return bookList.size
    }

    fun setBooks(it: List<Book>?) {
        bookList = it!!
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private class BookViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun setData(a: String, b: String, p: Int) {
            itemView.author.text = a
            itemView.book.text = b
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So did you find some solution !

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer: [How to update RecyclerView Adapter Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data) I think that You have to `notifyDataSetChanged` from observer method not inside the adapter class.

```
viewModel.allBooks.observe(this, Observer { books ->
    books?.let {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: changed")
        bookListAdapter.setBooks(books)
        bookListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
})
```

```
fun setBooks(it: List<Book>) {
    bookList = it
}
```

---

Also, when You use Room I think You can try to use [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil). It will automatically refresh layout when it has to be refreshed and is much faster than calling `notifyDataSetChanged` every time Your data is changed.

Comment: I did try that too, but still not working, I only see one record, there must be something else.