# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout and java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I keep getting the error "`E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`" when the RecyclerView list is shown. I'm getting data correctly from API but I got  "`void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`"

I know this question has been asked a lot before but I checked most of the questions and none has worked for me.

This is my fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private View view;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Result> arrayList;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
    private PostAdapter postAdapter;
    private MaterialToolbar toolbar;
    private SharedPreferences userPref;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_home,container,false);
        return view;

    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        init();
    }
    private void init() {

        userPref = getContext().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerHome);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        refreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.swipeHome);
        toolbar =(MaterialToolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbarHome);
        ((HomeActivity)getContext()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getResults();

        refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                getResults();
            }
        });
    }

    private void getResults() {//Working Fine}
        
}
```

My adapter:

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostsHolder>{
    private ArrayList<Result> list;
    private Context context;

       public PostAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Result> list) {
            this.list = new ArrayList<Result>(list);
            this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_home, parent, false);
        return new PostsHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostsHolder holder, int position) {
        Result result = list.get(position);
        holder.imgPostDate.setText(result.getDate());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
   public static class PostsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView imgPostProfile,imgPostName,imgPostDate;
        private ImageButton btnPostOption;

        public PostsHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgPostProfile =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPostProfile);
            imgPostName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPostName);
            imgPostDate =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPostDate);
            btnPostOption =(ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnPostOption);
        }
    }
}
```

I modified my code according to the answers I found to similar questions but none of them worked.

layout_home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarHome"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaCoSISBottomAppBar"
        app:title=""
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">
        <!--    <ImageView-->
        <!--        android:layout_width="100dp"-->
        <!--        android:layout_height="40dp"-->
        <!--        android:src="@drawable/logo_dark"/>-->
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/swipeHome"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerHome"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

layout_post

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imgPostProfile"
                android:layout_width="60sp"
                android:layout_height="60sp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_circle"
                android:text="MC"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imgPostName"
                    android:text="BBAD1252 Social Harmony and Business Skills Development"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imgPostDate"
                    android:text="12 Novermber 2020"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorLightGrey"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPostOption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_vert_24"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@color/colorLightGrey"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: The log indicates that you forgot to attach the adapter to the `RecyclerView`. Did you forget to call `RecyclerView#setAdapter`?

Comment: recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter); is called in getResults() methods

Comment: `holder.imgPostDate.setText(result.getDate())` is the line that caused the error. Seems like `holder.imgPostDate` was null. Can you attach the xml of `R.layout.layout_home`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onCreateViewHolder` you inflated the wrong xml. It should've been `R.layout.layout_post`

```
@NonNull
@Override
public PostsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_post, parent, false);
    return new PostsHolder(view);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent from error `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`, you should call `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` inside your `init();` method.

Then after you have your data you should notify the adapter in order to display your data by calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` or using any other notify methods. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48959184/10176064) answer for other notify methods.

Answer (score 0):

If your `getResults()` is where you're calling your `recyclerview.setAdapter()`, you're calling setAdapter too late. You need to make sure your adapter is set during `onCreateView()` so that the Recyclerview isn't being skipped while drawing the layout.

Answer (score 0):

No Adapter Attached; Skipping layout:
you should setadapter in your main thread methods of fragment; then add or update data to adapter

Nullpointer at settext [at adapter]: In onCreateViewHolder you inflated the wrong xml. It should be R.layout.layout_post instead of R.layout.layout_home