# How to create a new EditText that is placed in the RecyclerView when Button is Pressed? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a button that when pressed, is supposed to create a new editText inside a recyclerView. And this should be repeatable until a set limit. Ex. 5 EditTexts.

I have tried this code below, but when the button is pressed, the app just crashes.

```
// add is the btn id
    add.setOnClickListener {
        val newText = EditText(this)
        //recyclerView is Recycler View in activity_main
        recyclerView.addView(newText)
    }
```

How could I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You only need update the data and refresh the adapter.

Review this post.

[Update RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data)