# Android how to sort RecyclerView List when using AsyncListDiffer?

Tags: android, sorting, android-recyclerview, android-asynclistdiffer

I have a RecyclerView that shows a list of CardViews.  I recently switched the project from using RecyclerView Adapter to using an AsyncListDiffer Adapter to take advantage of adapter updates on a background thread.    I have converted over all previous CRUD and filter methods for the list but cannot get the sort method working.

I have different types or categories of CardViews and I would like to sort by the types/categories.  I clone the existing list mCards so the "behind the scenes" DiffUtil will see it as a different list, as compared to the existing list that I wanted to sort.  And then I use AsynListDiffer's submitList().

The list is not sorting.  What am I missing here?

MainActivity:

```
private static List<Card> mCards = null;

...
mCardViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CardViewModel.class);
mCardViewModel.getAllCards().observe(this,(cards -> {

    mCards = cards;
    cardsAdapter.submitList(mCards);
})); 
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(cardsAdapter);

A click on a "Sort" TextView runs the following code:

ArrayList<Card> sortItems = new ArrayList<>();
for (Card card : mCards) {
    sortItems.add(card.clone());
}
Collections.sort(sortItems, new Comparator<Card>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Card cardFirst, Card cardSecond) {
        return cardFirst.getType().compareTo(cardSecond.getType());
    }
});
cardsAdapter.submitList(sortItems);
// mRecyclerView.setAdapter(cardsAdapter);  // Adding this did not help
```

AsyncListDifferAdapter:

```
public AsyncListDifferAdapter(Context context) {

    this.mListItems = new AsyncListDiffer<>(this, DIFF_CALLBACK);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}

public void submitList(List<Quickcard> list) {

    if (list != null) {
        mListItems.submitList(list);
    }
}

public static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Card> DIFF_CALLBACK
        = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Card>() {

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Card oldItem, @NonNull Card newItem) {

        // User properties may have changed if reloaded from the DB, but ID is fixed
        return oldItem.getId() == newItem.getId();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Card oldItem, @NonNull Card newItem) {
        return oldItem.equals(newItem);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getChangePayload(@NonNull Card oldItem, @NonNull Card newItem) {
        return super.getChangePayload(oldItem, newItem);
    }
};
```

Model:

```
@Entity(tableName = "cards")
public class Card implements Parcelable, Cloneable {
// Parcelable code not shown for brevity
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "cardId")
public int id;
@ColumnInfo(name = "cardType")
private String type;

@Ignore
public Card(int id, String type) {
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}
public String getType() {
    return this.type;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if (obj == this)
        return true;

    else if (obj instanceof Card) {

        Card card = (Card) obj;

        return id == card.getId() &&
            type.equals(card.getType());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}  

@NonNull
@Override
public Card clone() {
    Card clone;
    try {
        clone = (Card) super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return clone;
}
```

Comment: Why are you cloning the object here ? any particular reason ?

Comment: I clone the existing list mCards so the "behind the scenes" DiffUtil will see it as a different list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using notifyDataSetChanged() we can use notifyItemMoved(). That solution gives us a nice animation of sorting. I put the sort order within the adapter. We need a displayOrderList that will contain the currently displayed elements because mDiffer.getCurrentList() doesn't change the order of elements after notifyItemMoved(). We first moved the element that is first sorted to the first place, the second sorted element to second place,... So inside the adapter put the following:

```
public void sortByType()
{
    List<Card> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(mDiffer.getCurrentList());
    sortedList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Card::getType));
    List<Card> displayOrderList = new ArrayList<>(mDiffer.getCurrentList());
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); ++i)
    {
        int toPos = sortedList.indexOf(displayOrderList.get(i));
        notifyItemMoved(i, toPos);
        listMoveTo(displayOrderList, i, toPos);
    }
}

private void listMoveTo(List<Card> list, int fromPos, int toPos)
{
    Card fromValue = list.get(fromPos);
    int delta = fromPos < toPos ? 1 : -1;
    for (int i = fromPos; i != toPos; i += delta) {
        list.set(i, list.get(i + delta));
    }
    list.set(toPos, fromValue);
}
```

and then call from activity cardsAdapter.sortByType();

Comment: I am away for holiday but will try as soon as I return.  Bounty awarded and answer accepted based on completeness.

Comment: @AJW thank you. Happy Holidays

Comment: The code "sortedList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Quickcard::getType));" requires Android OS API level 24.  What can I use for API < 24?

Comment: for java to sort based on property look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is in below method

```
public void submitList(List<Quickcard> list) {
    
        if (list != null) {
            mListItems.submitList(list);
        }
}
```

because here first you need to clear old arraylist "mListItems" using

```
mListItems.clear();
//then add new data 
 

if (list != null) {
    mListItems.addAll(list);
}
 
//now notify adapter
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Or Also you can direct notify adapter after sorting.
First set adapter and pass your main list in adapter's constructor

```
Collections.sort(sortItems, new Comparator<Card>() {
@Override
public int compare(Card cardFirst, Card cardSecond) {
    return cardFirst.getType().compareTo(cardSecond.getType());
}
```

});

```
//now direct notify adpter
your_adapter_object.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I will try to clear the adapter list and then addAll().  But the reason to use the AsyncListDiffer to update the update is because it is more efficient at updates and occurs on a background thread rather than relying on the heavy notifyDataSetChanged() method.

Comment: Also the notifyDataSetChanged() occurs on the main thread.

Comment: but without notifyDataSetChanged() how can adapter will know that data is updated. if data is updated in submitList() so list also updated but how adapter will now? Without notify I don't think it will update.

Answer (score 0):

> I clone the existing list mCards so the "behind the scenes" DiffUtil will see it as a different list

`DiffUtil` will detect changes by your implementation of `DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Card>`, so when you clone a card you just create a new instance of it with the same `ID`, therefor `DiffUtil` sees it as the same item because you are checking if the items are the same based on their `ID`:

```
 @Override
public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Card oldItem, @NonNull Card newItem) {

    // User properties may have changed if reloaded from the DB, but ID is fixed
    return oldItem.getId() == newItem.getId();
}
```

but because the cloned object's reference is different from the original item, `DiffUitl` will detect the items content change, because of:

```
@Override
public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Card oldItem, @NonNull Card newItem) {
    return oldItem.equals(newItem);
}
```

so `DiffUtil` will call `adapter.notifyItemChanged(updateIndex)` and will update the `viewHolder` in that index, but it won't change the order of items in the `recyclerView`.

There seems to be another problem in your sort code. You say

> I would like to sort by the types/categories

but you are sorting your list alphabetically every time you click the `textView`. This code will give you same result every time you run it and won't change the order of `recyclerView` assuming the original list is sorted in the first hand. If the original list isn't sorted, clicking the `textView` will change the order just once.