# How to reflesh RecycleView on Fragment after dismiss() DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android

Could you tell me the way to refresh data on RecycleView on Fragment.
On DialogFragment, there are some TextInputEditText, and users could change the data.
After users closed DialogFragment with dismiss(), RecycleView isn't changed.

Tried to use Intetnt back to RecycleView, but I think it is not correct way.
My environment is JAVA, Android Studio.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StartActivityForResult, it is the best way to get you modified data, here's a link to documentation and how to integrated it [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Answer (score 0):

You must notify all reorganized observer that the data set is altered to get visual effects using notifyDataSetChanged().[More details on notifyDataSetChanged()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data)

[This link also shows the use of notifyDataSetChanged()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data)