# Volley Request too slow

Tags: android, json, android-volley

my app crashes because of the following;

loadJsonFromAsset() method reads the JSON file after writing it with the update() method, but instead it goes straight to the reading part and my app crashes because the file ***video.json*** doesn't exist, JSON doesn't get written, it has to do with how slow the Volley request is? Or is how I create the file? I write and read the JSON file to cache it on the user's phone and if the file already exists on the phone it goes straight to the reading part(but I haven't implemented it if file exits). For example, it works if I remove the reading part of my code loadJSONFromAsset() and instead run the update() method the JSON file gets created with the JSON data I requested and then if I re-run the program with the loadJSOnFromAsset() and bam I read the data and my app doesn't crash.I think my problem is that I'm storing the cache to slowly?

loadJsonFromAsstet() reads JSON

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {

    update();

    String json = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream is = getActivity().openFileInput("video.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Fetching Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    }

    return json;

}
```

update(); Writes JSON with the requested data

```
public void update(){
    // Formulate the request and handle the response.

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, (String )null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    try {
                        FileOutputStream fos = getActivity().openFileOutput("video.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
                        out.write(response.toString());
                        out.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Fetching Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    //remove cash
    jsonObjectRequest.setShouldCache(false);
    mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not trying to read from file before you make sure that it was successfully loaded and saved. So, you need first to call `update()` method and take json inside `onResponse`.

Now your `onResponse` is called after you are trying to read from file (because it is asynchronous) and so you get error.

Comment: Yep exactly the problem here, but how can I be sure it was successfully loaded and saved?

Comment: Make sure that you write and read properly: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/how-to-read-write-string-from-a-file-in-android). And you read only in `onResponse`

Comment: How can I update the recyclerviewview with the data after the request?

Comment: @MadBoy you need to update your RecyclerAdapter's data and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` . Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053610/best-way-to-update-data-with-a-recyclerview-adapter) answer for example