# Loading images from the custom video gallery

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, video-gallery

I'm working on a page in which I have a button which takes you to the video gallery which I have created. From this you select some videos(thumbnails) and then hit the arrow to come back to the same place from where I hit the button to come to the Custom gallery with the selected videos.

Basically the map goes like this :

**Button(from AddFragment)->VideoGallery->Select videos-> AddFragment with selected videos which is visible inside the recycler view**

Now when I hit the button I come to my videogallery but when I select some videos from the gallery and come back to the AddFragment it shows nothing and one error comes up that is **E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout**

Now I have used Bundle to extract the sent data and populate it in my AddFragment.

I'm giving out the code for you :

**1. AddFragment.java**

```
public class AddFragment extends Fragment {

private ImageButton nextActivity;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ProgressDialog videoProgressDialog;
ArrayList<File> checkedList = new ArrayList<>();
ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
Button button;

public AddFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);

    nextActivity = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.gotoButton);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_add_view);

    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonToGallery);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getContext(),VideoGalleryActivity.class));
        }
    });

    return view;
}

//making adapter for RecyclerView which loads the desired files
class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>{

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private ArrayList<File> fileName;

    public ImageAdapter(ArrayList<File> checkedList) {

        fileName = checkedList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        Log.e("ADAPTER SETTING","DOING");
        //getting the passed value from videogallery
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        ArrayList<String> getValue = bundle.getStringArrayList("sendData");
        Log.e("RECEIVED_DATA======",getValue.toString());

        //adding the files to the list
        for(String pathName : getValue){
            File filePath = new File(pathName);
            checkedList.add(filePath);
        }

        //setting the adapter
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(checkedList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        View items = mInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_added_video,
                parent,false);
        items.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(215,215));
        return new ViewHolder(items);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if(fileName != null){
            bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(fileName.get(position).toString(),1);
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fileName.size();
    }
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    //public ImageButton imageButton;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        //imageButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addVideos);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.galleryImageView);
    }
} }
```

**2. fragment_add.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
tools:context="in.pinelane.myhovi.AddFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:padding="19dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Choose Videos"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gotoButton"
        android:layout_width="25sp"
        android:layout_height="25sp"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonToGallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Gallery"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/grid_add_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Inflates this layout
**custom_added_video.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
android:layout_marginStart="3dp">

<!--<ImageButton-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/addVideos"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_black_24dp"-->
    <!--android:layout_margin="3dp"-->
    <!--android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"-->
    <!--android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>-->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/galleryImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Any idea would be of great help! Thanks

I've tried defining the below code in onCreate but I got a NullPointerException so I defined the same inside the onCreateViewHolder but no result just **No Adapter attached; skipping layout**

```
Log.e("ADAPTER SETTING","DOING");
        //getting the passed value from videogallery
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        ArrayList<String> getValue = bundle.getStringArrayList("sendData");
        Log.e("RECEIVED_DATA======",getValue.toString());

        //adding the files to the list
        for(String pathName : getValue){
            File filePath = new File(pathName);
            checkedList.add(filePath);
        }

        //setting the adapter
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(checkedList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**EDITS**

I've made some changes inside my code and user **onActivityResult** and **startActivityForResult** in this fragment but still no result. My AddFragment is still blank and not showing any result

**Edited AddFragment.java**

```
public class AddFragment extends Fragment {

private ImageButton nextActivity;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<File> checkedList = new ArrayList<>();
ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
Button button;
private static final int CustomGallerySelectId = 1;//Set Intent Id

public AddFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);

    nextActivity = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.gotoButton);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_add_view);

    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonToGallery);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(getContext(),VideoGalleryActivity.class),CustomGallerySelectId);
        }
    });

    //setting the adapter
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(checkedList);
    GridLayoutManager videoGrid = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),3);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(videoGrid);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode){
        case CustomGallerySelectId :
            if(requestCode == RESULT_OK){
                Log.e("ADAPTER SETTING","DOING");
                //getting the passed value from videogallery
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                ArrayList<String> getValue = bundle.getStringArrayList("sendData");
                Log.e("RECEIVED_DATA======",getValue.toString());

                //adding the files to the list
                for(String pathName : getValue) {
                    File filePath = new File(pathName);
                    checkedList.add(filePath);
                }

            }
    }
}

//making adapter for RecyclerView which loads the desired files
class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>{

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private ArrayList<File> fileName;

    public ImageAdapter(ArrayList<File> checkedList) {

        fileName = checkedList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View items = mInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_added_video,
                parent,false);
        items.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(215,215));
        return new ViewHolder(items);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if(fileName != null){
            bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(fileName.get(position).toString(),1);
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fileName.size();
    }
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    //public ImageButton imageButton;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        //imageButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addVideos);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.galleryImageView);
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this code:

```
    //setting the adapter
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(checkedList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

to your `createView()` method.

In `createView` you are inflating the layout, you are finding the `RecyclerView` but you are not setting an adapter to it. The `RecyclerView` doesn't have any data to show, so it's skipped from the layout for a performance boost. You should also set a `LayoutManager`. If you need a simple list, you should use `LinearLayoutManager`.

The `createViewHolder()` method is called once for each visible element of your `RecyclerView`. It's not the right place to perform the initial setup of your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: I've done some the changes like this but still no result :  //setting the adapter
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(checkedList);
        GridLayoutManager videoGrid = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),3);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(videoGrid);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: Are you actually adding any items to your adapter?

Comment: I've made some changes in my code and yes in my ImageAdapter all the things are defined which is the data that came from the VideoGallery

Comment: You are not updating your adapter items in the correct way in `onActivityResult`. Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053610/best-way-to-update-data-with-a-recyclerview-adapter for details

Comment: I've done this. There was a problem inside the putExtra, I was not sending the data in putArrayListExtra()